# How to control fan speed?

Tags: power-management, lm-sensors

How can I control the computer's fan speed?

On Windows there is a wonderful program called [SpeedFan](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/SpeedFan).

Comment: I put simple cron solution for ATI cards here http://askubuntu.com/a/875241/375427

Comment: On linux, `fancontrol` is configured using `pwmconfig`.  Use `watch sensors` to observe sensors under CPU and GPU load. Use those values at idle and full load to set `MINTEMP` and `MAXTEMP` respectively, with `INTERVAL=1`. This ramps your fans in realtime as load increases. This is the most active cooling, providing a baseline for further tweaking. Run `pwmconfig` once, and then edit  `/etc/fancontrol` directly. Run `sudo service fancontrol restart` after each tweak.

Answer (score 220, accepted):

### Note before starting:

This functionality depends on both your hardware and software. If your hardware doesn't support fan speed controls, or doesn't show them to the OS, it is very likely that you could not use this solution. If it does, but the software (aka kernel) doesn't know how to control it, you are without luck.

---

1. Install the [lm-sensors](https://apps.ubuntu.com/cat/applications/lm-sensors) and [fancontrol](https://snapcraft.io/search?q=fancontrol) packages.
2. Configure **lm-sensors** as follows:

   1. In terminal type `sudo sensors-detect` and answer YES to all YES/no questions.
      *(Potentially, this can damage your system or cause system crash. For a lot of systems, it is safe. There is no guarantee that this process will not damage your system permanently, I just think that chance of such critical failure is **really really low**. Saving all your work for eventual crashes/freezes/restarts before handling system configuration is always good idea. If you feel unsure, read the comments and try to search a web and get some high-level overview before YES-ing everything, maybe being selective with your YES-es will still be enough)*
   2. At the end of sensors-detect, a list of modules that need to be loaded will be displayed. Type "yes" to have sensors-detect insert those modules into /etc/modules, or edit /etc/modules yourself.
   3. Run `sudo service kmod start`  This will read the changes you made to `/etc/modules` in step 2, and insert the new modules into the kernel.
      **Note**: If you're running Ubuntu 12.04 or lower, this 3rd step command should be replaced by `sudo service module-init-tools restart`
3. Configure **fancontrol**

   1. In terminal type `sudo pwmconfig` . This script will stop each fan for 5 seconds to find out which fans can be controlled by which PWM handle. After script loops through all fans, you can configure which fan corresponds to which temperature.
   2. You will have to specify what sensors to use. This is a bit tricky. If you have just one fan, make sure to use a temperature sensor for your core to base the fancontrol speed on.
   3. Run through the prompts and save the changes to the default location.
   4. Make adjustments to fine-tune `/etc/fancontrol` and use `sudo service fancontrol restart` to apply your changes. (In my case I set interval to 2 seconds.)
4. Set up **fancontrol** service

   1. Run `sudo service fancontrol start`. This will also make the fancontrol service run automatically at system startup.

In my case `/etc/fancontrol` for CPU I used:

Settings for hwmon0/device/pwm2:
(Depends on hwmon0/device/temp2_input)
(Controls hwmon0/device/fan2_input)

```
INTERVAL=2
MINTEMP=40  
MAXTEMP=60  
MINSTART=150  
MINSTOP=0  
MINPWM=0  
MAXPWM=255
```

and on a different system it is:

```
INTERVAL=10
DEVPATH=hwmon1=devices/platform/coretemp.0 hwmon2=devices/platform/nct6775.2608
DEVNAME=hwmon1=coretemp hwmon2=nct6779
FCTEMPS=hwmon2/pwm2=hwmon1/temp2_input
FCFANS=hwmon2/pwm2=hwmon2/fan2_input
MINTEMP=hwmon2/pwm2=49
MAXTEMP=hwmon2/pwm2=83
MINSTART=hwmon2/pwm2=150
MINSTOP=hwmon2/pwm2=15
MINPWM=hwmon2/pwm2=14
MAXPWM=hwmon2/pwm2=255
```

[This man page](https://www.systutorials.com/docs/linux/man/8-fancontrol/) gives some useful info on the settings and what they really do.

Comment: I tried to follow your guide, but got stuck at step three with this error:

/usr/sbin/pwmconfig: There are no pwm-capable sensor modules installed

Comment: I had the same problem with pwmconfig until I ran sudo sensors-detect

Comment: What to do if sudo sensors-detect doesn't come up with any sensors? --> Sorry, no sensors were detected. Either your system has no sensors, or they are not supported, or they are connected to an I2C or SMBus adapter that is not supported. If you find out what chips are on your board, check http://www.lm-sensors.org/wiki/Devices for driver status.

Comment: it would be nice if you would explain how to make `fancontrol` running on boot. Also, I experience a problem after every reboot saying `Configuration appears to be outdated, please run pwmconfig again` when starting `sudo fancontrol`

Comment: module init tools unrecognized service

Comment: If you're having trouble, be sure to check your dmesg for error messages. In my case, recent kernel changes prevented me from loading the necessary driver, and I had to add `acpi_enforce_resources=lax` to my kernel options to get the old functionality back. See also: http://goo.gl/tUcr36

Comment: *WARNING:* Do *NOT* answer to all `sensors-detect` questions with yes. I did that, and I had the most disturbing system crash!

Comment: I've tried this and I can't get any further than sudo pwmconfig, because I get: "There are no pwm-capable sensor modules installed". This is after the sensors-detect command does find an 'Intel digital thermal sensor'. I've also tried that kernel parameter. Can anyone suggest a solution?

Comment: @bukzor had the right fix for pwmconfig and my Asus motherboard (M2NPV-VM).  The instructions I used  for adding acpi lax boot option is on sister site, http://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/97974/how-do-i-remove-acpi-warning-on-boot

Comment: "In my case for CPU I used: "... where do we put this?

Comment: I would like to reiterate: Do NOT answer all `sensors-detect` questions with "Yes", it can PERMANENTLY damage your computer.

Comment: @ panzi, you wrote "**WARNING: Do NOT answer to all sensors-detect questions with yes. I did that, and I had the most disturbing system crash!**" Can you specify which question(s)  should not be answered with "Yes"?

Comment: @ stomstack, you wrote “**I would like to reiterate: Do NOT answer all sensors-detect questions with "Yes", it can PERMANENTLY damage your computer.**” Can you specify which question(s)  should not be answered with "Yes"?

Comment: On my i5-8265U CPU `sensors-detect` cannot detect the fans, so `sensors` cannot show them either. [I asked for a solution here](https://askubuntu.com/questions/1162598/show-fan-speed-of-i5-8265u-cpu-in-kubuntu)

Comment: I got this:
`Found the following PWM controls:`
`cat: hwmon4/pwm1: Input/output error`
`hwmon4/pwm1           current value: `
`/usr/sbin/pwmconfig: line 181: echo: write error: Input/output error`

Comment: IT IS RECOMMENDED TO USE THE DEFAULTS. HITTING ENTER WILL SELECT THE DEFAULT VALUE FOR A QUESTION WHICH IS GENERALLY THE ONE IN THE CAPITAL LETTERS.

```Did you understand what is mentioned in this comment? [YES/no] *Hits Enter* ```
YES is selected

Comment: I had to run "sudo service kmod restart" until pwmconfig found something! not just start

Comment: https://gist.github.com/bakman2/e801f342aaa7cade62d7bd54fd3eabd8 This fixed my issues with pwmconfig on Aorus Elite x570

Comment: See, now this is why Linux is such a pain for normal people. On Windows you have a multitude of easy graphical options that _just work_. On Linux you have a heap of commands to run in the terminal (that are easy to mess up if you're new) and then you don't even get a GUI. Pretty awful user experience (unless you're a dev, and used to this stuff).

Comment: cant even install fan control in amd64 laptop, hp pavilion gaming

Comment: Just a note:  If your motherboard has the 4 pin fan controller but your fan is a three wire fan then PWM speed control will not work.  Upgrade to a 4 wire fan.

Comment: On a ThinkPad P1 Gen 5 running Tuxedo US (Ubuntu 22.04), answering all `sensors-detect` questions with yes didn't lead to any crash, but running `sudo pwmconfig` after `sudo service kmod start` errored with "hwmon6/pwm1_enable stuck to 2 - Manual control mode not supported, skipping hwmon6/pwm1. - There are no usable PWM outputs."

Answer (score 60):

If you own a **ThinkPad**, there's a piece of software called `thinkfan` that does exactly this. As the name obviously suggests, it is specifically made for ThinkPads (`thinkpad_acpi`).

The `thinkfan` software is available in the standard ubuntu software repositories, but it does require a few steps to configure.

Here's an easy step-by-step guide:

[http://www.lxle.net/forums/discussion/821/how-to-set-up-thinkfan-on-a-lenovo-thinkpad-t430/p1](http://staff.science.uva.nl/~kholshei/thinkfan_guide/)

(which is basically a translated version of this German guide:
http://thinkwiki.de/Thinkfan)

---

### Relevant Information from Post:

**Step 1.** Install the thinkfan software and the sensors:

```
sudo apt-get install thinkfan lm-sensors
```

**Step 2.** Make sure that the daemon controls the fan by editting the thinkpad.conf file:

```
sudo nano /etc/modprobe.d/thinkfan.conf
```

by adding the following line:

```
options thinkpad_acpi fan_control=1
```

**Step 3.** Make the daemon load automatically at start-up by editting the file:

```
sudo nano /etc/default/thinkfan
```

making sure that the START key is set to yes, i.e. there should be a line that says:

```
START=yes
```

**Step 4.** Detect your laptop's sensors:

```
sudo sensors-detect
```

and just choose the default answers whenever you're prompted by hitting Enter.

**Step 5.** Load the new modules. From ubuntu 13.10 this done by:

```
sudo service kmod start
```

while for previous versions like 13.04 you instead will need to do:

```
sudo service module-init-tools start
```

**Step 6.** Figure out which sensors are in use:

```
sensors
```

(the ones that indicate 0 degrees are not in use, I don't know why those are "detected" too). Remember which ones are in use.

**Step 7.** Find out the full paths of these sensors:

```
find /sys/devices -type f -name "temp*_input"
```

The output should be a list of paths like /sys/devices/...

**Step 8.** Copy-paste the paths to the sensors into the configuration file /etc/thinkpad.conf. To do this, first open up the file:

```
sudo nano /etc/thinkfan.conf
```

There should already be a line like

```
#sensor /proc/acpi/ibm/thermal (0, 10, 15, 2, 10, 5, 0, 3, 0, 3)
```

(the #-symbol means that that line is commented out). Add a line starting with sensor (without the #-symbol) and copy-paste you first sensor. Repeat this if you have more than one sensor. For example, on my machine, the output in step 7 yields

```
/sys/devices/virtual/hwmon/hwmon0/temp1_input
/sys/devices/platform/thinkpad_hwmon/temp3_input
/sys/devices/platform/thinkpad_hwmon/temp4_input
/sys/devices/platform/thinkpad_hwmon/temp5_input
/sys/devices/platform/thinkpad_hwmon/temp6_input
/sys/devices/platform/thinkpad_hwmon/temp7_input
/sys/devices/platform/thinkpad_hwmon/temp1_input
/sys/devices/platform/thinkpad_hwmon/temp8_input
/sys/devices/platform/thinkpad_hwmon/temp2_input
/sys/devices/platform/coretemp.0/temp4_input
/sys/devices/platform/coretemp.0/temp2_input
```

The ones that are in use in my machine are the ones in the first and the last two lines, so I added the three lines:

```
sensor /sys/devices/virtual/hwmon/hwmon0/temp1_input
sensor /sys/devices/platform/coretemp.0/temp4_input
sensor /sys/devices/platform/coretemp.0/temp2_input
```

**Step 9.** Finally we can set the fan speed levels in the configuration file. Open the /etc/thinkpad.conf file if it wasn't open already.

```
sudo nano /etc/thinkfan.conf
```

The fan levels I use on my ThinkPad x201 are:

```
(0, 0, 51)
(1, 50, 52)
(2, 51, 55)
(3, 54, 58)
(4, 56, 63)
(5, 60, 70)
(6, 66, 79)
(7, 74, 92)
(127, 85, 32767)
```

The last line ensures full fan speed (127 = "disengaged" i.e. unregulated). You can fiddle with these levels to fit your needs/wishes, but PLEASE BE CAREFUL!

**Step 10.** Reboot. Everything should work now. In order to check whether thinkpad is runnning correctly, use

```
sudo thinkfan -n
```

which starts thinkfan in verbose mode. You might want to stop the thinkfan daemon first:

```
sudo /etc/init.d/thinkfan stop
```

If you want to start the thinkfan daemon again, type:

```
sudo /etc/init.d/thinkfan start
```

Just to be complete, my /etc/thinkfan.conf configuration file is:

```
# IMPORTANT:
#
# To keep your HD from overheating, you have to specify a correction value for
# the sensor that has the HD's temperature. You need to do this because
# thinkfan uses only the highest temperature it can find in the system, and
# that'll most likely never be your HD, as most HDs are already out of spec
# when they reach 55 °C.
# Correction values are applied from left to right in the same order as the
# temperatures are read from the file.
#
# For example:
# sensor /proc/acpi/ibm/thermal (0, 0, 10)
# will add a fixed value of 10 °C the 3rd value read from that file. Check out
# http://www.thinkwiki.org/wiki/Thermal_Sensors to find out how much you may
# want to add to certain temperatures.

# Syntax:
# (LEVEL, LOW, HIGH)
# LEVEL is the fan level to use (0-7 with thinkpad_acpi)
# LOW is the temperature at which to step down to the previous level
# HIGH is the temperature at which to step up to the next level
# All numbers are integers.
#

# I use this on my T61p:
#sensor /proc/acpi/ibm/thermal (0, 10, 15, 2, 10, 5, 0, 3, 0, 3)

#(0, 0, 55)
#(1, 48, 60)
#(2, 50, 61)
#(3, 52, 63)
#(4, 56, 65)
#(5, 59, 66)
#(7, 63, 32767)


# My settings for my ThinkPad X201: (kris)

sensor /sys/devices/virtual/hwmon/hwmon0/temp1_input
sensor /sys/devices/platform/coretemp.0/temp4_input
sensor /sys/devices/platform/coretemp.0/temp2_input

(0, 0, 51)
(1, 50, 52)
(2, 51, 55)
(3, 54, 58)
(4, 56, 63)
(5, 60, 70)
(6, 66, 79)
(7, 74, 92)
(127, 85, 32767)
```

Comment: One comment: you want to have larger overlap of temperature values as in the table commented out. Especially in the 45-55 range. Otherwise, the fan speed keeps flipping. That's very disturbing. (Constant fan noise does not disturb so much as fluctuating noise.)

Comment: We (the linux community) really suck at UX. :( Setting a fan speed shouldn't be a 10 step process.

Comment: @Alexander If you feel strongly about this, you're free to write and maintain a little program to automate this process.

Comment: @Kris I'd be more inclined to modify the original program to not have such a nonsensical configuration process. Alas, I dont have a thinkpad, I was just passing by this post looking for thr fan control options available out there.

Comment: `/etc/modprobe.d/thinkfan.conf ` does not exist in my Ubuntu 14.04. What now?

Comment: @Youda008 create it like this: `echo "options thinkpad_acpi fan_control=1" > /etc/modprobe.d/thinkfan.conf`

Comment: Would this work on other laptops too? I own a Lenovo Yoga 730-15IWL

Comment: I don't know. Why not give it a go?

Comment: @Kris , thanks for your answer, but I have one more question about it: is it possible to control the periodicity of checking sensors? I mean that, sometimes the temperature of specific sensor changes too fast, and thinkfan immediately changes the fan speed too. I see the option `-s`, but I think it doesn't works correctly.

Comment: Check out HongboZhu's comment above. What helps is if you have larger overlap in the temperature ranges, so that thinkfan doesn't want to switch back and forth too quickly

Comment: Does it work for ThinkStations? I have P330 ThinkStation Tower and I need to control fans.

Comment: Have you tried?

Comment: now instead of `sensor` you have to use `hwmon`.

Comment: How do you know which sensors are used by your machine and which ones aren't?

Comment: @Kris: I was never an Apple fan, but this kind of low-level stuff required to deal with the stupid thermal management on the P1 Gen5, makes me want to return it and get a MacBook Pro. I've never once heard the fans on that machine in 5 months of usage. Nor has it ever crashed, or booted without a battery detected, or without a touchpad, or the [various problems that ThinkPads have](https://www.reddit.com/r/linuxhardware/comments/u0mgfc/linux_laptop_best_hardware_right_now/idgfjaj/).

Comment: @DanDascalescu Just slam the keyboard and chuck it out the window mate 

Comment: same question as @sequence asked: the command `sensors` does not provide the names similar to the output of the command `find /sys/devices -type f -name "temp*_input"`, so no idea how to identify those sensors. I tried just using all of them, but then get errors like `ERROR: Module thinkpad_acpi doesn't seem to support fan_control` or `ERROR: ~TpFanDriver: Resetting fan control in /proc/acpi/ibm/fan: Invalid argument`. If you could help, that would be great, thanks.

Comment: (the errors mentioned in my previous comment were caused by smth else, I had to add the use in step 2 the line  `options thinkpad_acpi fan_control=1 experimental=1` and that resolved the issues)

Answer (score 23):

For several Dell computers you can install i8kutils package:

```
sudo apt install i8kutils
```

If you have a non-tested Dell (like Dell XPS 14z, Dell XPS 15 9550 or even Alienware M15 R4), you might have to force loading of kernel module:

```
sudo modprobe i8k force=1
```

If you want to control the fans you might need to follow a more thorough guide: [Fan switches between full speed and off on Dell G5](https://askubuntu.com/questions/1218270/fan-switches-between-full-speed-and-off-on-dell-g5/1319565#1319565)

Comment: I have Dell XPS 14 L421X. <code>sensors</code> showed no fans. after installing i8kutils package,  I get sensors
coretemp-isa-0000
Adapter: ISA adapter
Physical id 0:  +54.0°C  (high = +87.0°C, crit = +105.0°C)
Core 0:         +50.0°C  (high = +87.0°C, crit = +105.0°C)
Core 1:         +52.0°C  (high = +87.0°C, crit = +105.0°C)

i8k-virtual-0
Adapter: Virtual device
Right Fan:      0 RPM
CPU:          +55.0°C

Comment: Does this work for hp?

Comment: @immortal-player , I think it won't. The kernel module is specifically designed for Dell machines.

Comment: Maybe add, that for Apple there is `macfanctld` and `mbpfan` and for ThinkPad, there's `thinkfan`

Comment: what about for older Toshiba Satellite machines?

Comment: ok so um... after i type these two commands, how exactly do I control the fan speed?

Comment: You will have three comands via the apt package: i8kctl, i8kfan, i8kmon @Michael

Comment: I've added an in-depth answer for newer dell laptops here: https://askubuntu.com/a/1319565/422405

Comment: Nice answer @KyleBaker ! I've done some of the things you mention there on my Dell XPS 15 9550

Answer (score 10):

Here is an **updated answer**, based on the [answer recommending thinkfan](https://askubuntu.com/a/402310) but working with Ubuntu 19.04, and also on other computers than just ThinkPads.

### 1. Setup

The instructions below apply to any ThinkPad that has the `/proc/acpi/ibm/fan` and `/proc/acpi/ibm/thermal` "legacy" devices. This avoids having to install the `lm-sensors` package.

However, you can still opt to install `lm-sensors`. It will give you more temperature sensors and more fine-grained control over your fans, namely in 256 PWM steps rather than the fixed steps "0-7 and 127" with the legacy devices. Also, since `thinkfan` now can work with `lm-sensors` sensors, it is no longer specific for IBM / Lenovo ThinkPad computers. Please refer to `man thinkfan` for using these "extended" sensor devices. Also, there is up-to-date information [in the German Thinkwiki](http://thinkwiki.de/Thinkfan).

1. Install the required package:

   ```
   sudo apt install thinkfan
   ```
2. Add the following line to `/etc/modprobe.d/thinkfan.conf`:

   ```
   options thinkpad_acpi fan_control=1
   ```
3. Configure the `thinkfan` service to start automatically at system start:

   1. Add a line `START=yes` to `/etc/default/thinkfan`
   2. Execute the following command ([source](https://askubuntu.com/a/1139269)):

      ```
      sudo systemctl enable thinkfan.service
      ```
4. Adapt `/etc/thinkfan.conf` with the right pointers to devices and the fan levels you want. The comments there provide documentation. On any Thinkpad with the legacy `fan` and `thermal` devices, the following should provide a good starting point (also should be safe for the hard disk, see comments in the file for more information). Note that this uses new keywords – the ones in the [other answer](https://askubuntu.com/a/402310) are now deprecated.

   ```
   tp_fan /proc/acpi/ibm/fan
   tp_thermal /proc/acpi/ibm/thermal

   (0, 0, 47)
   (1, 43, 52)
   (2, 48, 55)
   (3, 51, 58)
   (4, 54, 63)
   (5, 59, 70)
   (6, 66, 79)
   (7, 74, 92)
   (127, 85, 32767)
   ```

### 2. Test

To test your setup (after a reboot), you can do as follows:

- In one terminal window, run `thinkfan` in non-daemonized mode so you can see its messages:

  ```
  sudo service thinkfan stop && sudo thinkfan -n
  ```
- In another terminal window, keep an eye on the current temperature values, supplying your temperature probe device if different:

  ```
  while true; do sleep 1; cat /proc/acpi/ibm/thermal; done
  ```
- In yet another terminal window, make some heat in the CPU (and interrupt it with <kbd>Ctrl</kbd> + <kbd>C</kbd> in case something in the thermal management does not function as expected):

  ```
  sudo apt install stress-ng
  stress-ng --cpu-1
  ```

Comment: Awesome. This solved it for my T490 with Pop_OS 19.04. The fan still comes on, but not the whole time.

Comment: Newer ThinkPad devices don't have `/proc/acpi/ibm/thermal`, so it's necessary to do some extra work for that case (conveniently listed on that wonderful German ThinkWiki page). I seem to have gotten it working for me, so I may update your answer or create another one. Thanks!

Comment: Cliff, what is the correct folder for this? I'm getting this error:
/proc/acpi/ibm/thermal: No such file or directory

add_sensor: Error getting temperature.
Refusing to run without usable config file!

Comment: OK.. I figured it out. I used this for my T480:
wmon /sys/devices/platform/coretemp.0/hwmon/hwmon1/temp1_input
hwmon /sys/devices/platform/coretemp.0/hwmon/hwmon1/temp5_input
hwmon /sys/devices/platform/coretemp.0/hwmon/hwmon1/temp2_input

(0, 0, 47)
(1, 43, 52)
(2, 48, 55)
(3, 51, 58)
(4, 54, 63)
(5, 59, 70)
(6, 66, 79)
(7, 74, 92)
(127, 85, 32767)

Comment: I could not find /etc/modprobe.d/thinkfan.conf, only /etc/default/thinkfan.conf

Answer (score 9):

Install and configure the [lm-sensors](http://packages.ubuntu.com/lm-sensors) and [fancontrol](http://packages.ubuntu.com/fancontrol) packages:

```
sudo apt-get install lm-sensors fancontrol
```

Documentation for configuring them is available on their man pages.

This is a function that is supposed to be provided by a ACPI-compliant BIOS, but it seems that most motherboard vendors don't bother to follow the standard.

Comment: Can you provide more detailed instructions on how to install and use them?

Comment: You can find that in the man page, or at www.lm-sensors.org.

Comment: I know, I just thought this answer could be better :)

Comment: The link that @psusi gave doesn't work, the new link is here: https://github.com/groeck/lm-sensors

Answer (score 7):

Try looking in the UEFI setup (or BIOS setup) of your PC. There might be a setting for fan control where you can put your fan into `Silent Mode`, `Performance Mode`, `Full Speed`, `Customize`, etc.

**How to access the UEFI settings**: Reboot your PC and the key for entering them will likely show up in one of the corners (e.g. `Press F2 to enter UEFI setup`)

[image: ASRock UEFI setup for fan control]

Comment: This is AskUbuntu not AskUEFI :)

Comment: @Maarten Sure, this solution is OS-independent, simple and does not require installing additional software.

Comment: @xjcl The link in your answer is dead.

Comment: Wayback machine to the rescue!

Answer (score 4):

The script I run every few seconds to keep my Dell server cool and quiet. Update the get_temp for your hardware.

```py
#!/bin/env python3

import os
import json

MIN_FAN = 5
MAX_FAN = 100

MIN_TEMP = 50 # fans at min at this temp
MAX_TEMP = 80 # fans at max at this temp

TEMP_POW = 3 # decrease for cooler server, increase for quiter

def get_temp():
    sensors = json.loads(os.popen('/usr/bin/sensors -j').read())
    temp0 = sensors["coretemp-isa-0000"]["Package id 0"]["temp1_input"]
    temp1 = sensors["coretemp-isa-0001"]["Package id 1"]["temp1_input"]
    return max(temp0, temp1)

def determine_fan_level(temp):
    x = min(1, max(0, (temp - MIN_TEMP) / (MAX_TEMP - MIN_TEMP)))
    return int(min(MAX_FAN, max(MIN_FAN, pow(x, TEMP_POW)*(MAX_FAN-MIN_FAN) + MIN_FAN)))

def set_fan(fan_level):
    # manual fan control
    os.system("ipmitool raw 0x30 0x30 0x01 0x00")
    # set fan level
    cmd = "ipmitool raw 0x30 0x30 0x02 0xff " + hex(fan_level)
    os.system(cmd)

temp = get_temp()
fan = determine_fan_level(temp)
print("temp", temp, "fan", fan)
set_fan(fan)
```

Comment: `Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/home/user/tmp/fan.py", line 31, in <module>
    temp = get_temp()
           ^^^^^^^^^^
  File "/home/user/tmp/fan.py", line 17, in get_temp
    temp1 = sensors["coretemp-isa-0001"]["Package id 1"]["temp1_input"]
            ~~~~~~~^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^
KeyError: 'coretemp-isa-0001'`

Comment: @alfC read "Update the get_temp for your hardware." Obviously your stuff is named differently.

Answer (score 2):

For a HP laptop the following scripts (which I'm **not** an author of) seem to work for me, but...

... link to the license first (it's too big to be included here): https://www.gnu.org/licenses/gpl-3.0.txt .

- [probook_ec.pl](https://raw.githubusercontent.com/k3mpaxl/fanspeed/master/probook_ec.pl):

```perl
#!/usr/bin/perl -w

# Copyright (C) 2007  Michael Kurz     michi.kurz (at) googlemail.com
# Copyright (C) 2007  Petr Tomasek     tomasek (#) etf,cuni,cz
# Copyright (C) 2007  Carlos Corbacho  cathectic (at) gmail.com
#
# Version 0.6.1 (2007-11-08)
#
# This program is free software; you can redistribute it and/or
# modify it under the terms of the GNU General Public License
# as published by the Free Software Foundation; either version 3
# of the License, or (at your option) any later version.
#
# This program is distributed in the hope that it will be useful,
# but WITHOUT ANY WARRANTY; without even the implied warranty of
# MERCHANTABILITY or FITNESS FOR A PARTICULAR PURPOSE.  See the
# GNU General Public License for more details.
# 
# You should have received a copy of the GNU General Public License
# along with this program; if not, write to the Free Software
# Foundation, Inc., 51 Franklin Street, Fifth Floor, Boston, MA  02110-1301, USA.


require 5.004;

use strict;
use Fcntl;
use POSIX;
use File::Basename;

sub initialize_ioports
{
  sysopen (IOPORTS, "/dev/port", O_RDWR)
    or die "/dev/port: $!\n";
  binmode IOPORTS;
}

sub close_ioports
{
  close (IOPORTS)
    or print "Warning: $!\n";
}



sub inb
{
  my ($res,$nrchars);
  sysseek IOPORTS, $_[0], 0 or return -1;
  $nrchars = sysread IOPORTS, $res, 1;
  return -1 if not defined $nrchars or $nrchars != 1;
  $res = unpack "C",$res ;
  return $res;
}

# $_[0]: value to write
# $_[1]: port to write
# Returns: -1 on failure, 0 on success.
sub outb
{
  if ($_[0] > 0xff)
  {
    my ($package, $filename, $line, $sub) = caller(1);
    print "\n*** Called outb with value=$_[1] from line $line\n",
          "*** (in $sub). PLEASE REPORT!\n",
          "*** Terminating.\n";
    exit(-1);
  }
  my $towrite = pack "C", $_[0];
  sysseek IOPORTS, $_[1], 0 or return -1;
  my $nrchars = syswrite IOPORTS, $towrite, 1;
  return -1 if not defined $nrchars or $nrchars != 1;
  return 0;
}

sub wait_write
{
    my $i = 0;
    while ((inb($_[0]) & 0x02) && ($i < 10000)) {
        sleep(0.01);
        $i++;
    }
    return -($i == 10000);
}

sub wait_read
{
    my $i = 0;
    while (!(inb($_[0]) & 0x01) && ($i < 10000)) {
        sleep(0.01);
        $i++;
    }
    return -($i == 10000);
}

sub wait_write_ec
{
    wait_write(0x66);
}

sub wait_read_ec
{
    wait_read(0x66);
}

sub send_ec
{
    if (!wait_write_ec()) { outb($_[0], 0x66); }
    if (!wait_write_ec()) { outb($_[1], 0x62); }
}

sub write_ec
{
    if (!wait_write_ec()) { outb(0x81, 0x66 ); }
    if (!wait_write_ec()) { outb($_[0], 0x62); }
    if (!wait_write_ec()) { outb($_[1], 0x62); }
}

sub read_ec
{
    if (!wait_write_ec()) { outb(0x80, 0x66 ); }
    if (!wait_write_ec()) { outb($_[0], 0x62); }
    if (!wait_read_ec())  { inb(0x62); }
}

sub write_kc
{
    if (!wait_write(0x64)) { outb($_[0], 0x64); }
    if (!wait_write(0x64)) { outb($_[1], 0x60); }
}

sub print_regs
{
    initialize_ioports();

    my @arr = ("00","10","20","30","40","50","60","70","80","90","A0","B0","C0","D0","E0","F0", "");

    my $i = 0;
    my $t = 0;
    print "\n  \t00\t01\t02\t03\t04\t05\t06\t07\t|\t08\t09\t0A\t0B\t0C\t0D\t0E\t0F\n";
    print "  \t__\t__\t__\t__\t__\t__\t__\t__\t|\t__\t__\t__\t__\t__\t__\t__\t__\n";
    print "00 |\t";
    for ($i = 0; $i < 256; $i++)
    {
        $t = read_ec($i);
        print $t;
        print "\t";
        if ((($i + 1) % 8) == 0){
            if ((($i + 1) % 16) == 0) {
                if ($i != 255) { print "\n$arr[(($i-(($i + 1) % 16)) / 16) + 1] |\t"; }
            } else {
                print "|\t";
            }
        }
    }
    
    print "\n";
    
    close_ioports();
}

sub write_temp
{
    initialize_ioports();
    write_ec($_[0],$_[1]);
    close_ioports();
}

sub testnum
{
    my $i;
    for ($i = 0; $i<256;$i++) {
        if ($_[0] eq "$i") { return 1 };
    }
    return 0;
}

my $ii;

if (!$ARGV[0]){
        print "wrong arguments!\n";
    print "usage:\n";
    print "\'probook_ec regs\' \t\t\t\tdumps all ec registers\n";
    print "\'probook_ec ledon\' \t\t\t\tswitch on 'mail LED' (WMID)\n";
    print "\'probook_ec ledoff\' \t\t\t\tswitch off 'mail LED' (WMID)\n";
    print "\'probook_ec getled\' \t\t\t\tget 'mail LED' status (WMID)\n";
    print "\'probook_ec getled2\' \t\t\t\tget 'mail LED' status(AMW0)\n";
    print "\'probook_ec getwireless\' \t\t\t\tget 'wireless' status (AMW0)\n";
    print "\'probook_ec gettouch\' \t\t\t\tis the touchpad disabled?\n";
    print "\'probook_ec setfanthresh <temp>\' \t\t\t\tset temperature threshhold to <temp>, DANGEROUS!\n";
    print "\'probook_ec getfanthresh\' \t\t\t\tget temperature threshhold\n";
    print "\'probook_ec <temp-number> <temperature>\' \tfor setting a temperature\n";
    print "where <temp-number> is from 0-7, and <temperture> is from 0-255\n";
    print "\'probook_ec ?= <reg>\' \t\tQuery register's value\n";
    print "\'probook_ec := <reg> <val>\' \tSet register's value\n";
    print "\'probook_ec +f <reg> <val>\' \tOr register's value with val (to set flags)\n";
    print "\'probook_ec -f <reg> <val>\' \tAnd register's value with ~val (to clear flags)\n";
    print "\'forcekc\' \tTry all possible values on writeable RAM of keyboard controller\n";
    print "\'kcw <cmd> <val>\' \tWrite a command and a value to the keyboard controller\n";
} elsif ($ARGV[0] eq "regs") {
    print_regs();
} elsif ($ARGV[0] eq "getled") {
    # TM2490 only (WMID)
    initialize_ioports();
    if (read_ec(0x9f)&0x01) {
        print "Mail LED on\n";
    } else {
        print "Mail LED off\n"; }
    close_ioports();
} elsif ($ARGV[0] eq "getled2") {
    # Aspire 5020 only (AMW0)
    initialize_ioports();
    if (read_ec(0x0A)&0x80) {
        print "Mail LED on\n";
    } else {
        print "Mail LED off\n"; }
    close_ioports();
} elsif ($ARGV[0] eq "getwireless") {
    # Aspire 5020 only (AMW0)
    initialize_ioports();
    if (read_ec(0x0A)&0x4) {
        print "Wireless on\n";
    } else {
        print "Wireless off\n"; }
    close_ioports();
} elsif ($ARGV[0] eq "gettouch") {
    # TM2490 only - needs testing
    initialize_ioports();
    if (read_ec(0x9e)&0x08) {
        print "touchpad disabled\n";
    } else {
        print "touchpad enabled\n"; }
    close_ioports();
} elsif ($ARGV[0] eq "?=") {
    initialize_ioports();
    my $r = hex($ARGV[1]);
    printf("REG[0x%02x] == 0x%02x\n", $r, read_ec($r));
    close_ioports();
} elsif ($ARGV[0] eq ":=") {
    initialize_ioports();
    my $r = hex($ARGV[1]);
    my $f = hex($ARGV[2]);
    my $val = read_ec($r);
    #printf("REG[0x%02x] == 0x%02x\n", $r, $val);
    #printf("REG[0x%02x] := 0x%02x\n", $r, $f);
        write_ec( $r, $f);
    #printf("REG[0x%02x] == 0x%02x\n", $r, read_ec($r));
    #echo "$r:$f\n" >> regs_set
    close_ioports();
} elsif ($ARGV[0] eq "FANCTL") {
        initialize_ioports();
        write_ec(0x22,1);
        write_ec(0x26,0x1F);
        #write_ec(0x2F,0xFF);
        #printf("REG[0x%02x] == 0x%02x\n", 0x1E, read_ec(0x1E));
        close_ioports();
        #`notify-send FANOFF`;
} elsif ($ARGV[0] eq "FANOFF") {
    initialize_ioports();
    write_ec(0x22,1);
    write_ec(0x26,0x1F);
    write_ec(0x2F,0xFF);
    #printf("REG[0x%02x] == 0x%02x\n", 0x1E, read_ec(0x1E));
    close_ioports();
        #`notify-send FANOFF`;
} elsif ($ARGV[0] eq "FANRST") {
        initialize_ioports();
        write_ec(0x22,0x01);
    write_ec(0x26,0x00);
        #printf("REG[0x%02x] == 0x%02x\n", 0x22, read_ec(0x22));
        close_ioports();
} elsif ($ARGV[0] eq "+f") {
    initialize_ioports();
    my $r = hex($ARGV[1]);
    my $f = hex($ARGV[2]);
    my $val = read_ec($r);
    printf("REG[0x%02x] == 0x%02x\n", $r, $val);
    printf("REG[0x%02x] := 0x%02x\n", $r, $val | $f);
        write_ec( $r, $val | $f);
    printf("REG[0x%02x] == 0x%02x\n", $r, read_ec($r));
    close_ioports();
} elsif ($ARGV[0] eq "-f") {
    initialize_ioports();
    my $r = hex($ARGV[1]);
    my $f = hex($ARGV[2]);
    my $val = read_ec($r);
    printf("REG[0x%02x] == 0x%02x\n", $r, $val);
    printf("REG[0x%02x] := 0x%02x\n", $r, $val & ~$f);
        write_ec( $r, $val & ~$f);
    printf("REG[0x%02x] == 0x%02x\n", $r, read_ec($r));
    close_ioports();
} elsif ($ARGV[0] eq "ledon") {
    # TM2490 only - needs testing
    initialize_ioports();
    if (!wait_write(0x64)) { outb(0x59, 0x64); }
    if (!wait_write(0x64)) { outb(0x92,   0x60); }
    close_ioports();
} elsif ($ARGV[0] eq "ledoff") {
    # TM2490 only - needs testing
    initialize_ioports();
    if (!wait_write(0x64)) { outb(0x59, 0x64); }
    if (!wait_write(0x64)) { outb(0x93,   0x60); }
    close_ioports();
} elsif ($ARGV[0] eq "getfanthresh") {
    initialize_ioports();
    $ii=read_ec(0xa9);
    close_ioports();
        print "Temperature threshhold: $ii (celsius)\n";
} elsif (($ARGV[0] eq "setfanthresh") && testnum($ARGV[1])) {
    write_temp(0xA9,$ARGV[1]);
} elsif ($ARGV[0] eq "setbright") {
    # Aspire 5020 only (AMW0)
    if ($ARGV[1] >= 0 && $ARGV[1] <= 15) {
        write_temp(0x83, $ARGV[1]);
    } else {
        print "second argument must be a number between 0 and 15\n";
    }
} elsif ($ARGV[0] eq "forcekc") {
    # Be smart - we only send the commands for writing to keyboard RAM
    initialize_ioports();
    my ($kbdata, $cont, $kbreg);
    for ($kbreg = 0x40; $kbreg <= 0x5f; $kbreg++) {
        for ($kbdata = 0; $kbdata < 256; $kbdata++) {
            write_kc($kbreg, $kbdata);

            print sprintf("%0#4x", $kbreg), ", ", sprintf("%0#4x", $kbdata), "\n";
            print "Continue? y/n: ";
            $cont = <STDIN>;
            if ($cont eq "n") {
                last;
            }
        }
    }
    close_ioports();
} elsif ($ARGV[0] eq "kcw") {
    initialize_ioports();
    write_kc($ARGV[1], $ARGV[2]);
    close_ioports();
} else {
    print "wrong arguments!\n";
}
```

- [fanslow.sh](https://raw.githubusercontent.com/k3mpaxl/fanspeed/master/fanslow.sh):

```bsh
#!/bin/bash

# Copyright (C) 2017  Gregor Bonney
#
# Version 2.0
#
#
# This program is free software; you can redistribute it and/or
# modify it under the terms of the GNU General Public License
# as published by the Free Software Foundation; either version 3
# of the License, or (at your option) any later version.
#
# This program is distributed in the hope that it will be useful,
# but WITHOUT ANY WARRANTY; without even the implied warranty of
# MERCHANTABILITY or FITNESS FOR A PARTICULAR PURPOSE.  See the
# GNU General Public License for more details.
# 
# You should have received a copy of the GNU General Public License
# along with this program; if not, write to the Free Software
# Foundation, Inc., 51 Franklin Street, Fifth Floor, Boston, MA  02110-1301, USA.

LOGFILE=/var/log/fanspeed.log
ECFILE=/etc/fanspeed/probook_ec.pl
COUNTER=0

######################################################

initFan()
{
  setFan 80
#  sleep 2
  $ECFILE FANOFF
}

setFan()
{
  SPEED=$1
  $ECFILE := 0x2F $SPEED
}

getTempAvg()
{
  CUR=0
  CPUTEMP=0

  while [ $CUR -lt $INTERVAL ]
  do
    #TMP=$(sensors | grep Physical | cut -b 18-19)
    TMP=$(cat /sys/class/hwmon/hwmon*/device/temp1_input | cut -b1-2)
    #TMP=$(sensors | grep "Physical" | awk '{print $4}' | tr -d '+°C' | cut -b 1-2)
    ((CPUTEMP=$CPUTEMP+$TMP))
    ((CUR=$CUR+1))
    sleep 1
  done
  ((CPUTEMP=$CPUTEMP/$INTERVAL))
}

detectNewSpeed()
{
  ((COUNTER=$COUNTER+$INTERVAL))

  if [ $CPUTEMP -le $TEMPFANSTARTSPEED ]
  then
    # CPU COOLED DOWN
     ((INTERVAL=$STEPS))
    if [ $LASTSPEED -gt 75 ]
    then
      if [ $COUNTER -gt $THROTTLEOFF ]
      then
        # STOP FAN AFTER CPU COOLED DOWN
        NEWSPEEDF=FF
      fi
    elif [ "$NEWSPEEDF" == "FF" ]
    then
      NEWSPEEDF=FF
    else
      ((NEWSPEEDF=$NEWSPEEDF+$INTERVAL))
    fi
  elif [ $CPUTEMP -gt $TEMPFANMAXSPEED ]
  then
    # CPU VERY HOT!!!
    NEWSPEEDF=0
    resetCounter
    ((INTERVAL=10))
  else
    # CPU TEMP IS BETWEEN START AND MAX SPEED
    if [ $CPUTEMP -le $LASTTEMP ]
    then
      if [ $COUNTER -gt $THROTTLESEC ]
      then
        #calculate fanspeed after $THROTTLESEC seconds
        calculateFanSpeed
        resetCounter
      fi
    else
      # CPU TEMP RAISED -> CALCULATE AGILITY
      calculateFanSpeed
      calculateNextInterval
      resetCounter
    fi
  fi

  echo $TEMPFANSTARTSPEED:$CPUTEMP:$TEMPFANMAXSPEED:$NEWSPEEDF:$NEXTINT:$INTERVAL:$THROTTLESEC:$COUNTER
  #printf "TMIN:%d TCUR:%d TMAX:%d FSPEED:%s SLEEP:%d CNT:%d\n" $TEMPFANSTARTSPEED $CPUTEMP $TEMPFANMAXSPEED $NEWSPEEDF $INTERVAL $COUNTER

  if [ "$LASTSPEED" != "$NEWSPEEDF" ]
  then
    setFan $NEWSPEEDF
  fi

  ((LASTTEMP=$CPUTEMP))
  ((LASTSPEED=$NEWSPEEDF))
}

calculateFanSpeed() {
  ((LASTSPEED=$NEWSPEEDF))
  ((NEWSPEEDF=($CPUTEMP-$TEMPFANMAXSPEED)*($CPUTEMP+$TEMPFANMAXSPEED)))
  ((NEWSPEEDF=$NEWSPEEDF*-24/1000))
  #if [ "$LASTSPEED" != "FF" ]; then
  #  ((TST=$LASTSPEED+$INTERVAL))
  #  if [ $TST -le $NEWSPEEDF ]
  #  then
  #    ((NEWSPEEDF=$LASTSPEED+$INTERVAL))
  #  fi
  #fi
}

resetCounter() {
  ((COUNTER=0))
}

calculateNextInterval() {
  #calculate next interval
  NEXTINT=0
  for i in `seq 0 $STEPS`;
  do
    if [ $NEXTINT -le $CPUTEMP ]
      then
      ((NEXTINT=($TEMPFANSTARTSPEED+(($TEMPFANMAXSPEED-$TEMPFANSTARTSPEED)*$i/$STEPS))))
      ((INTERVAL=1+$STEPS-$i))
    fi
  done
}

##################################################


sleep 10

initFan

#use the average temperature of $INTERVAL seconds
INTERVAL=5
#throttle down after $THROTTLESEC seconds
THROTTLESEC=30
#set fan off after on lowest setting for $THROTTLEOFF seconds
THROTTLEOFF=80
#temperatures in celsius
TEMPFANSTARTSPEED=52 #56
TEMPFANMAXSPEED=80

STEPS=8


NEWSPEEDF=74
LASTTEMP=55
LASTSPEED=75

while [ true ]
do
  getTempAvg
  detectNewSpeed
done
```

What I've modified in "fanslow.sh" though was at least:

- Changed `ECFILE=/etc/fanspeed/probook_ec.pl` to match my path.
- Added
  `TMP=$(sensors | grep "Package id 0:" | awk '{print $4}' | tr -d '+°C' | cut -b 1-2)` after `#TMP=$(sensors | grep "Physical" | awk '{print $4}' | tr -d '+°C' | cut -b 1-2)` and commented out (added "#" at the beginning of the line) a default `TMP=$(cat /sys/class/hwmon/hwmon*/device/temp1_input | cut -b1-2)`.
- Changed value in `TEMPFANSTARTSPEED=52 #56` at the end of the script.
- Changed value in `TEMPFANMAXSPEED=80` at the end of the script.

There is one more script that I haven't used I believe, but maybe it'll end up being helpful for someone:

- [init.d_fanspeed](https://raw.githubusercontent.com/k3mpaxl/fanspeed/master/init.d_fanspeed):

```bsh
#! /bin/sh
#
# Copyright (C) 2017  Gregor Bonney
#
# Version 2.0
#
#
# This program is free software; you can redistribute it and/or
# modify it under the terms of the GNU General Public License
# as published by the Free Software Foundation; either version 3
# of the License, or (at your option) any later version.
#
# This program is distributed in the hope that it will be useful,
# but WITHOUT ANY WARRANTY; without even the implied warranty of
# MERCHANTABILITY or FITNESS FOR A PARTICULAR PURPOSE.  See the
# GNU General Public License for more details.
# 
# You should have received a copy of the GNU General Public License
# along with this program; if not, write to the Free Software
# Foundation, Inc., 51 Franklin Street, Fifth Floor, Boston, MA  02110-1301, USA.

case "$1" in
start)
echo "Starting " $0

cd /etc/fanspeed/
./fanslow.sh >> /var/log/fanspeed &>> /dev/null &

;;
stop)
echo "Stopping " $0
killall fanslow.sh
/etc/fanspeed/probook_ec.pl FANRST
#
# Do something to stop the target platform here
#
;;
restart)
echo "Restarting " $0
$0 stop
$0 start
;;
status)
echo  "Status Not Implemented"
#
# Do something to process status checks here.
#
;;
*)
echo "Usage: /etc/init.d/$0 {start|stop}"
exit 1
;;
esac
exit 0
```

Source: https://ubuntuforums.org/showthread.php?t=2008756&s=43a5ddf387823582cf47e3b25dbab100&p=12422983#post12422983 , https://ubuntuforums.org/showthread.php?t=2008756&page=4&p=13447421#post13447421 .

Comment: It works! Amazing, thank you very much for these links. Have an oldie HP 8460p, can turn it into a silent home server at last :). You also mentioned you changed `TEMPFANSTARTSPEED` & `TEMPFANMAXSPEED`, don't recall which values did you choose?

Comment: @AS , about the specific values... I've experienced with that. To be honest I don't really use the script right now, but it seems I ended up with `TEMPFANSTARTSPEED=72` (but I've tried more: 70, 68, 80, 52, 56 possibly at least) and `TEMPFANSTARTSPEED=72` (similarly: 80, 0, 50). I believe it's worth checking out what temperature is displayed as "crit" when You run `sensors` as I think it may vary from processor to processor. And You're welcome, I'm really glad it helped, to God be the glory. ^^ Thank You for letting me know.