# Changing fan speed for eee pc 900

Tags: 11.10, ubuntu-netbook, fan, eeepc

I was wondering if there was a program that would let me change the speed of my eee pc 900 fan. I have tried lmsensors and eee-control and could not get them to install.

Does anyone know how to either get them working or know another program that will work?

Answer (score 1):

Check [How to control fan speed?](https://askubuntu.com/questions/22108/how-to-control-fan-speed) [@GrizzLy](https://askubuntu.com/users/6564/grizzly)

1. Install lm-sensors and fancontrol packages

   1. Configure **lm-sensors**
   2. In terminal type `sudo sensors-detect` and answer YES to all YES/no questions.
   3. At the end of sensors-detect, a list of modules that needs to be loaded will displayed. Type "yes" to have sensors-detect insert those modules into /etc/modules, or edit /etc/modules yourself.
   4. run `sudo /etc/init.d/module-init-tools restart` This will read the changes you made to /etc/modules in step 3, and insert the new modules into the kernel.
   5. Configure **fancontrol**
   6. In terminal type `sudo pwmconfig` . This script will stop each fan for 5 seconds to find out which fans can be controlled by which PWM handle. After script loops trought all fans, you can configure which fan corresponds to which temperature.
   7. In my case i set interval to 2 seconds.
   8. Run **fancontrol**
   9. `sudo fancontrol` and leave it open in console,

In my case for CPU i used

> Settings for hwmon0/device/pwm2:
>     Depends on hwmon0/device/temp2_input
>     Controls hwmon0/device/fan2_input
>     MINTEMP=40
>     MAXTEMP=60
>     MINSTART=150
>     MINSTOP=0
>     MINPWM=0
>     MAXPWM=255

Comment: ok thanks. i also have one more question. is it bad for the computer if i have it running at full power all the time/

Comment: didnt understand