# How do I set my EeePC fan to aggressive cooling in Ubuntu 15.04?

Tags: 15.04, fan, eeepc, fancontrol

I have installed Ubuntu 15.04 and have faced a rather nasty problem: the computer shuts down in just some minutes (or almost immediately in case of active usage) because of overheating (I can notice a "thermal zone critical" message in the shut down console).

I have also noticed that the fan is almost always off although it seems not broken (it does work on occasion, especially when I am using bare console after switching to it with Ctrl+Alt+F1, but that is not enough).

I have tried installing the lm-sensors package as [this answer](https://askubuntu.com/questions/105810/changing-fan-speed-for-eee-pc-900) suggests but pwmconfig still says no compatible sensors found even though sensors-detect does find an AMD sensor and says there is a module for it autoloaded.

I would like the fan to go aggressive and work almost always instead of trying to save power but don't know how to achieve this. Please help.

Comment: Would you be willing to do a hardware mod?

Comment: Also (I know it's for Debian, but they're pretty similar) try this: https://wiki.debian.org/DebianEeePC/TipsAndTricks#Software_Control_of_the_fan_speed

Comment: @Zacharee1 Well, I am going to consider hardware mod if nothing else helps I'd will obviously prefer to manage without that if possible. Regarding the Debian link - `echo 1 > pwm1_enable` and `n > fan1_pwm` seem to change nothing at all (I have also tried playing with the numbers). I am going to continue experimenting with other things mentioned in that article.

Comment: @Zacharee1I think I am considering a hardware mod. Might I ask if you have got schematics? By the way, I have installed the AMD fglrx drivers and the whole thing stopped working - now it boots to an empty black screen with a lone cursor where no button but Power (it actually triggers normal software shutdown with the Ubuntu logo) works.

Comment: I don't have any resources or guides on hand, but I'm pretty sure that's a common computer, so you should have no trouble finding something. As for the driver problems, press Ctrl+alt+f1 to get into a TTY and uninstall the drivers as if you were using the terminal.