# How to control CPU fan with no pwm-capable sensors?

Tags: cpu, fan, fancontrol

I've tried to follow the directions on this thread:
[How to control fan speed?](https://askubuntu.com/questions/22108/how-to-control-fan-speed)

But `pwmconfig` gives me this error:

```
/usr/sbin/pwmconfig: There are no pwm-capable sensor modules installed
```

Is there anything I can still do to control my cpu fan speed?

---

```
$ sudo lshw -C system 
marco-linux               
    description: All In One
    product: iMac11,1 ()
    vendor: Apple Inc.
    version: 1.0
    serial: W80184DT5PJ
    width: 64 bits
    capabilities: smbios-2.4 dmi-2.4 vsyscall32
    configuration: boot=normal chassis=all-in-one family=iMac uuid=D2FE9523-6304-3457-A5D0-9E895170B482
```

Comment: What motherboard do you have?

Comment: Here's my output of 'lspci'...can you please help me out. I'm facing the same problem with my HP Pavilion Dv7 quad edition Laptop. root@venkat:/# lspci 00:00.0 Host bridge: Intel Corporation 2nd Generation Core Processor Family DRAM Controller (rev 09) 00:01.0 PCI bridge: Intel Corporation Xeon E3-1200/2nd Generation Core Processor Family PCI Express Root Port (rev 09) 00:02.0 VGA compatible controller: Intel Corporation 2nd Generation Core Processor Family Integrated Graphics Controller (rev 09) 00:16.0 Communication controller: Intel Corporation 6 Series/C200 Series Chipset Family MEI Contro