# How to change CPU fan speed on ThinkPad?

Tags: 12.04, thinkpad, cpu, fan, fancontrol

I checked [this post](https://askubuntu.com/q/170575/71313) on AskUbuntu, but like the OP my BIOS does not have a setting for 'smart fan'. My BIOS though has something similar called 'Thermal Performance' wherein it's already set to maximum performance.

But using Hardware Sensors Indicator my fan speed barely reaches 3000 RPM (it's usually stuck around 2600 to 2700 RPM) compared to the indicated RPM of my laptop which is 5400 RPM.

There is a fan control setup for 10.04 specifically for Thinkpad [here](http://www.thinkwiki.org/wiki/Installing_Ubuntu_10.04_%28Lucid_Lynx%29_on_a_ThinkPad_Z61m#Set_up_Fan_Control) but I don't want to risk it since it's meant for a rather outdated distro already.

Is there a way change the fan speed if I can't access it through BIOS?

I'm using ThinkPad R61i 12.04 64-bit, 160 GB HDD, Intel T5870, 4 GB RAM.

Comment: Where did you get the info about the 5400 RPM?

Comment: I googled the laptop's specs http://www.laptopspec.net/2009/08/lenovo-thinkpad-r61i7732cto-14-1-inch-laptop/

Comment: The 5400 RPM refers to the Hard Drive speed, and not the fan speed.

Comment: Ah, I'm sorry for that. I read that as the fan speed. But based on the link provided below (http://www.thinkwiki.org/wiki/How_to_control_fan_speed), the ThinkPad R61 speed can be increased ie., (ThinkPad R61i (fan levels RPM: 0 = off, 1 = 2689, 2 = 2729, 3 = 3059, 4 = 3047, 5 = 3051, 6 = 3515, 7 = 3468, full-speed/disengaged = 4119~4200)mod.#7650-D7G@+/-2yr.used) although I'm hopeless on how to do the adjustment.

Comment: You can download the [ThinkPad-Fan-Control](https://github.com/Stanko/ThinkPad-Fan-Control)

Comment: Would it be all right to ask for a step by step on how to install this, or would it be better to open another question for it?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How to control fan speed?](http://askubuntu.com/questions/22108/how-to-control-fan-speed)

Answer (score 2):

If you want direct control via the ThinkPad driver then the following wiki page is very helpful:

http://www.thinkwiki.org/wiki/How_to_control_fan_speed

Comment: Thank you for this, but unfortunately I'm clueless on how to do the steps since they will be terminal-based. Is there somewhere I can get a step by step for this? Also, are the steps offered still applicable to 12.04?

Comment: -1 You shouldn't be answering a question with just a link.

Answer (score -1):

The link above has a perfect solution to the issue. I'm reproducing the link here:

http://staff.science.uva.nl/~kholshei/thinkfan_guide/

Follow all the instructions in the guide of the above link. Then in the /etc/thinkfan.conf file, make the following entry at the end:

(5,    0,     40)

(7,    38,    45)

(64,    44,    60)

Only the above three statements in the matrix are enough. Delete or comment the previous matrix entry. Reboot, and now the fan runs at full speed when temperature rises to 45C and drops to the previous speed at 44C. You may change the values slightly to suit your PC.

Comment: The vital link is broken

Comment: Link is broken. (HTTP 404) -1

Comment: The `thinkfan` tools seems to be hosted at http://thinkfan.sourceforge.net/.  thinkfan v0.9.1 is available on Ubuntu 18.04 via `apt-get install thinkpad` (2020-05-08).