# Fan very loud in Ubuntu 12.10

Tags: fan, noise

I recently installed 12.10 on my Desktop PC, moving away from Windows 7.
For some reason, the fan in my computer is making an enormous amount of noise (it is running at full speed constantly).

Under Windows 7, the fan would slow itself down and run at an acceptable noise level.  Now, it is nearly unbearable.

Checked the processes, and none are taking up a huge load on the CPU.

Please help as I really can't endure this noise, and I do not want to go back to Windows 7 on this box.

Some specs:
- Intel 2.26 duo core
- ATI 4870
- 4GB 
- 650W power supply

Comment: Possible duplicate of http://askubuntu.com/questions/22108/how-to-control-fan-speed

Comment: I have the same problem with Ubuntu 12.10 dual boot with windows 8
I can't use it like this Dell XPS8300 Computer is making an enormous amount of noise (it is running at full speed constantly). Ubuntu 12.04 was working fine Any idea?

Comment: I'm not convinced this is a duplicate.  The answers are possibly suggesting a divergent cause, anyway.

Comment: I've tried everything.  The best solution was to install the AMD proprietary drivers.  Seems to calm the fan down significantly, however, at the sacrifice of 2D acceleration.  The AMD drivers are ridiculously horrible for 2D applications.

Comment: I would recommend first checking the CPU, HDD and motherboard temperature. The fan speed might be indicating something.

Comment: I forgot about this thread.  Just wanted to say that Ubuntu ended up killing my GPU fan, and I got a new video card, and the problem was fine after that.  It must of been some driver issue with my particular video card.

Answer (score 3):

I had this after installation, but it went back to normal after doing a re-boot. That was 3 days ago and it has been ok since then.

Answer (score 3):

I have a similar problem in Xubuntu 11.10 which has developed excessive fan noise in the last few months. Looking at the processes tab in Sys monitor, Firefox does appear to be using a lot of CPU % when doing things like switching/opening tabs, even scrolling with 3 tabs open uses 20%

For me it has only occured in the last few months, previous to that it was fine so maybe it is related to Firefox specifically?

Asus G71V Core 2 Duo T9400 @ 2.53GHz, 4GB Ram, Geforce 9600M

Comment: So now I am on Xubuntu 12.10, 3.5.0-18-generic. Is this the kernel overheating issue? #sesnors gives `code`acpitz-virtual-0
Adapter: Virtual device
temp1:        +50.0°C  (crit = +110.0°C)

coretemp-isa-0000
Adapter: ISA adapter
Core 0:       +46.0°C  (high = +105.0°C, crit = +105.0°C)
Core 1:       +47.0°C  (high = +105.0°C, crit = +105.0°C)`code`

Answer (score 3):

I had the same problem. I'm not sure if this is still a problem in the kernel 3+, but my fan behaves now more or less as under Windows 7.  I followed the advice for a fix [here (webupd8.org).](http://www.webupd8.org/2011/06/linux-kernel-power-issue-fix.html)

Comment: Didnt help much :(

Answer (score 2):

you should consider installing jupiter, since this fixed my blazing fans.

you can select power modes with it, and it's very easy to control.
I always install this on my laptops, and set it to power on demand(personal opinion).

open terminal and do this.

add the repository

```
sudo add-apt-repository ppa:webupd8team/jupiter
```

update

```
sudo apt-get update
```

install jupiter

```
sudo apt-get install jupiter
```

and to other people reading this and are using an Asus EEPC netbook, install this asswell

```
sudo apt-get install jupiter-support-eee
```

Have a nice day :)

Answer (score 2):

You might try to determine which fan is having the problem.

I have a Dell Dimension 9200 with an NVidia graphics card (GeForce 7900 GS) and was having the same issue. It turned out, it was the graphics card fan that was the underlying noise maker. I was able to fix this by using the proprietary NVidia driver instead of the Nouveau driver.

I changed using the Software Center:
1) Open Software Center
2) Select Edit | Software Sources
3) Select the Additional Drivers tab
4) Choose Using NVIDIA binary Xorg driver, kernel module and VDPAU library from nvidia-304-updates (proprietary)
5) Press the Apply Changes button
6) Quit the dialog, reboot, and viola, no more fan noise.

I used the instructions found [here](http://www.dedoimedo.com/computers/ubuntu-ringtail-nvidia.html) as my guide for changing the drivers.