# The fan on my laptop runs constantly in Ubuntu

Tags: fancontrol

Maybe someone asked this already, but i must ask why my cooler constantly blowing when i start ubuntu? When I'm on Windows 7 its normal, cooler blowing just when I play some game.

Here is my Laptop configuration :

AMD® Fusion APU Quad Core A8-3500M 1.5 GHz,
Graphic card AMD Radeon HD 6520G 1GB
Ram 8GB DDR3
HDD 500 GB

Comment: which version of ubuntu are you using? and have you tried installing the graphic card drivers on ubuntu?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How to control fan speed?](https://askubuntu.com/questions/22108/how-to-control-fan-speed) and [Laptop fan constantly running at a high speed](https://askubuntu.com/questions/428551)

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Laptop fan constantly running at a high speed](https://askubuntu.com/questions/428551/laptop-fan-constantly-running-at-a-high-speed)

Answer (score 1):

I guess you haven't set up fancontrol yet. Fancontrol is an application which slows down your fans according to the temperature of your cpu. [This](http://ubuntuforums.org/showthread.php?t=42737) is an excellent guide to set it up.

Answer (score 0):

I had same problem, and it bothered me on several distros.
Even though your post is few years old problem is still existent.
Try to purge all ATI supplied graphic card drivers, and chose open source. For me it helped not only to turn fan off, but also to make processors to work on lower loads when idle.