# Ubuntu 15.10 runs very slowly on my Dell Inspiron laptop

Tags: dual-boot, drivers, nvidia, 15.10, inspiron

I bought a new [Dell Inspiron:](http://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/B015PYYDMQ) laptop.

```
Processor: i5-6300HQ          
HDD: 230GB 5400RPM                  
RAM: 8GB 
NVIDIA GeForce GTX 960M 4GB GDDR5
```

I am dual booting Windows 10 and Ubuntu 15.10. For some reason Ubuntu appears to be running very slowly, even slower than when I used Ubuntu on my dual core 4GB RAM laptop. Is there anything I can do about this? I am already running the version 352.63 NVIDIA graphics driver. I installed it from the Ubuntu Software Center's Additional drivers tab.

It takes a lot of time to boot and also the applications take too long to open and respond slowly.

Attaching a screenshot from SMART test.

[image]
<sup>(Click image to enlarge)</sup>

Is the problem only related to slow hard drive, or is it because of some other reason too?

Comment: How is it slow exactly ? Boot time ? HDD read/write ? CPU time ? Graphics rendering ? Saying it is slow helps no one understand your issue, please update your question with what exactly is slow about it.

Comment: sorry for being vague.just edited the question again.
I think the problem is little bit more than the slow hdd. because i was using the same hdd in my old laptop and ubuntu was working just fine.
Could this problem be because of Skylake processor support for ubuntu.

Comment: Is the fan spinning and CPU frequency as expected? You can install `cpufrequtils` and run `cpufreq-info` to check. (I have fan and overheating problems, which I usually only notice when the machine slows down!)

Comment: yes my fan is constantly running.
I read in one of the [posts](http://askubuntu.com/questions/428551/laptop-fan-constantly-running-at-a-high-speed) that GRUB command line "quiet splash" controls the fan speed. But due to some issues with my Nvidia GTX 960 I removed that line and used "nomodeset" . Can that be the problem and can i do something to resolve this.