# Fan is running constantly after installing ubuntu 16.04

Tags: 16.04, overheating, fan

I've installed ubuntu 16.04 and since first login fan is running constantly. I've tried several desktop envirnment and several version of nvidia graphic card but the same problem. 
I've check system monitor and cpu usage is normal. 
Additionally I've tried installing kernel 4.6 but fan is still running and also installing laptop-mode-tools and tlp had no benefit.

In my ubuntu 14.04 everything was good and acpi -t result was around 42-50 c but in ubuntu 16.04 acpi -t is 52-63 c and fan is still running !

Comment: It's possible that some process is consuming CPU which is producing heat therefore the fan is running more than before.  From a terminal window use the `top` command to determine if there's a process with high CPU%.  If it's an application that you don't need all the time (eg firefox!) kill it (say with `killall firefox`) and see if the temperature goes down and the fan slows.

Comment: I've used top command but every thing is well and cpu usage is normal

Comment: You could also try running `sensors` to get more temperature info.  This may require installation of lm-sensors.  Another command that may be of help is `uptime` - the last 3 fields show the "load" averages over 1 minute, 5 minutes, and 15 minutes.  Just focus on the first of the numbers - is it 1 or more?  That would indicate a lot of process activity. Also try searching for other similar reports such as [1](http://askubuntu.com/questions/428551/laptop-fan-constantly-running-at-a-high-speed)

Comment: Thanks, the sensor output is : `acpitz-virtual-0
Adapter: Virtual device
temp1:        +50.0°C  (crit = +102.0°C)

coretemp-isa-0000
Adapter: ISA adapter
Physical id 0:  +50.0°C  (high = +87.0°C, crit = +105.0°C)
Core 0:         +49.0°C  (high = +87.0°C, crit = +105.0°C)
Core 1:         +51.0°C  (high = +87.0°C, crit = +105.0°C)
`

Comment: and the uptime output is : `00:04:49 up 16 min,  2 users,  load average: 0.15, 0.25, 0.32
` I think the load and processing usage is normal but fan is still running !!!

Answer (score 0):

Try the solution I have posted in [here](https://kasunsiyambalapitiya.wordpress.com/2017/05/08/fixing-constantly-running-fan-on-dell-laptops-when-running-ubuntu-16-04/?preview_id=17&preview_nonce=d4d9bc6679)

Comment: You should expand your answer with a summary such as it installs i8kutils. In my case this conflicted with Intel thermals causing video stuttering every 10 seconds or so. I found a utility that works well with others I think it was called tlp.