# frequent abnormal shutdowns/system crashes

Tags: 12.10, kernel, shutdown, overheating

It's been almost 5 days since I have installed Ubuntu and almost 6th time that my laptop has been crashed entirely and it shuts down abnormally. Actually, it heats up and I have to wait for 20 odd minutes before I can turn it on again. A message appears that my PC crashed due to overheating which may damage my hard disk. The crashes happened when I tried to open some application that freeze my PC not even giving me enough time to go to system monitor and end process. Sometimes the culprit application which caused crash is Ever-pad, sometime it's team-viewer, sometimes it's some other.

This is something very serious. The last crash occurred at 09:14:40. Kindly click [here](http://ubuntuone.com/72AnxYR8ooKSfHGHp0noIS) to view system log. I want to stick to Ubuntu and the same laptop as I had serious issues with Windows and I nearly went out to dump my laptop and purchase a more powerful system. Below are my hw/os specs. Kindly advice on how to resolve this issue

Ubuntu 12.10
Kernal 3.5.0-18-generic
GNOME 3.6.0
Memory 2.0GB
Processor: Genuine Intel CPU T2500@2.00GHz x 2
Available Disk Space: 63.7 GB

Thanks in advance

Comment: This may be unrelated, but what is you graphic card?

Comment: [screenshot for Graphic Card](http://ubuntuone.com/1OVxH1dcbyo7t0Nj404AcX)

Comment: Awesome on posting the syslog btw. That made it dead simple to diagnose the problem.

Answer (score 1):

Did you get a chance to run a update after installation?  There is a known problem with Everpad, plus others, that is fixed with an update.
https://github.com/nvbn/everpad/issues/35

Answer (score 0):

From your syslog

> Nov 28 09:14:40 donchoudhry-Latitude-D620 kernel: [32171.266551] CPU0: Core temperature above threshold, cpu clock throttled (total events = 19)

Your frying your chip. Check your fans, make sure there running, clean them and if needed adjust the speed higher.

[See this answer](https://askubuntu.com/questions/22108/how-to-control-fan-speed) for fan speed adjustments. First though, clean and check your fans.