# How to set the tempreture at which the fan must speed up - laptop

Tags: laptop, fan

I have HP Probook 4530s and the fan speeds up at around 45C then when it reaches 35C slows down and repeats. In the interval between 35-45 it barely works and this results in very annoying speed up of the fan every 2 minutes. How can set a higher threshold at which it will speed up and how can I keep the tempreture between the two intervals stable ( I mean the fan will not turn off but keep a steady speed ).
Thank you in advance.

Comment: possible duplicate of [How to control fan speed?](http://askubuntu.com/questions/22108/how-to-control-fan-speed)

Answer (score 1):

Fan speed and the temperature at which the fan hits certain speeds can be controlled in linux via a combination of packages lm-sensors and fancontrol, though on my HP laptop I could never get it to work properly, I believe because HP controls this via the bios, but it may just be I didn't research enough.

I ended up changing the cpu governor to conservative and changing the conservative governor settings this ultimately made my computer run cooler and more efficiently (less fan cycling).

I found these two pages that helped me manipulate the governor and put my setting permanently in /etc/rc.local to load them on each reboot http://www.pantz.org/software/cpufreq/usingcpufreqonlinux.html 
http://www.thinkwiki.org/wiki/How_to_use_cpufrequtils