# Fan speed in ubuntu: pwmconfig no pwm-capable sensor modules installed

Tags: 12.10, fan, temperature, fancontrol, lm-sensors

I followed [this guide](https://askubuntu.com/questions/22108/how-to-control-fan-speed) about how to control fan speed in Ubuntu, but it doesn't work with my laptop (Dell Inspiron 15r).

I installed [lm-sensors](http://packages.ubuntu.com/lm-sensors)[image: Install lm-sensors] and [fancontrol](http://packages.ubuntu.com/fancontrol)[image: Install fancontrol] packages. Then I configured **lm-sensors** by typing:

`sudo sensors-detect`

and I answered YES to all questions.
At the end I had this message:

> Driver `coretemp':
>   * Chip`Intel digital thermal sensor' (confidence: 9)
>
> To load everything that is needed, add this to /etc/modules:
>
> ----cut here----
>
> `#Chip drivers`
>
> coretemp
>
> ----cut here----

- I added the suggested lines to `/etc/modules`.
- I rebooted my laptop.

Now the problem: when I try to configure fancontrol typing:

`sudo pwmconfig`

I get an error:

> /usr/sbin/pwmconfig: There are no pwm-capable sensor modules installed

I spent most of the day looking for a solution but I had no luck.

**What should I do now?**

Comment: I have the same problem now with the MB Asus Prime Z490-P and can't seem to be able to find a solution :(

Answer (score 10, accepted):

I partially solved the problem using i8kutils. Here's a guide about it:

[Keenformatics -  How to solve Dell laptops fan issues in Ubuntu](https://www.keenformatics.com/how-to-solve-dell-laptops-fan-issues-in-ubuntu)

and a discussion here on askubuntu:

[Dell Inspiron 5521 i7-3317U Fan CPU too Noisy](https://askubuntu.com/questions/303234/dell-inspiron-5521-i7-3317u-fan-cpu-too-noisy/308548#308548)

## Here are the main steps as written on Keenformatics site (my blog).
How To solve Dell laptops fan issues in Ubuntu

1. First of all, let's download and install i8kutils. Open your terminal and write:

`sudo apt-get install i8kutils`

2. Now you've got to add i8k to your modules. Open the modules file:

`sudo gedit /etc/modules`

and add the string "**i8k**" (without quotes) to the file. Save and exit.

3. Create an `i8k.conf` file

   `sudo vim /etc/modprobe.d/i8k.conf`

   and fill it with this code:

   `options i8k force=1`

Note: Some older guides will tell you to create a /modprobe.d/options file. The "options" file isn't used anymore on Ubuntu. What does matter is that you create a file with a .conf extension (the filename isn't important, but I decided to name it i8k.conf for clarity). So beware of older i8kmon configuration guides.

4. Now restart your computer, or run this code to make i8k run:

`sudo modprobe i8k force=1`

5. We will now create a i8kmon.conf file which will tell the i8kmon utility how to behave.

`sudo gedit /etc/i8kmon.conf`

Paste the following code in it:

```
    # Run as daemon, override with --daemon option
    set config(daemon)      0
     
    # Automatic fan control, override with --auto option
    set config(auto)        1
     
    # Report status on stdout, override with --verbose option
    set config(verbose) 1
     
    # Status check timeout (seconds), override with --timeout option
    set config(timeout) 20
     
    # Temperature thresholds: {fan_speeds low_ac high_ac low_batt high_batt}
    set config(0)   {{-1 0}  -1  40  -1  40}
    set config(1)   {{-1 1}  30  60  30  60}
    set config(2)   {{-1 2}  53  128  53  128}
     
    # For computer with 2 fans, use a variant of this instead:
    # Temperature thresholds: {fan_speeds low_ac high_ac low_batt high_batt}
    # set config(0) {{-1 0}  -1  52  -1  65}
    # set config(1) {{-1 1}  41  66  55  75}
    # set config(2) {{-1 1}  55  80  65  85}
    # set config(3) {{-1 2}  70 128  75 128}
     
    # end of file
```

This has been edited to match my Dell Inspiron 15r 5521 fan configuration (and I hope I did it well). If you want more informations take a look at the documentation on Ubuntu Manuals: http://manpages.ubuntu.com/manpages/gutsy/man1/i8kmon.1.html

6. Now you should be able to run **i8kmon** from your terminal and see if (and how) it's working. Simply run:

`i8kmon`

Finished!

Comment: Does this work for hp?

Comment: @ImmortalPlayer recording to https://launchpad.net/i8kutils it is only for some models of Dell computers...

Comment: It seems that it worked on HP: https://askubuntu.com/a/400956/270501, but I haven't tried it on my HP laptop...

Comment: It doesn't seem to work for Dell Inspiron 15 3511 i5 with Debian.