# psensor on Ubuntu 16.04 LTS

Tags: drivers, fan, temperature, psensor

I am running Ubuntu on an ASUS Maximus VIII Formula mobo.  All has been running fine for several months.  Running Psensor 1.1.5

Problems with monitoring temps and fan speeds.  The most obvious issue is that the Corsair H75 CPU cooler fans shows zero RPM.  The cooler water pump isn't even listed.

Another major issue is that when I change the sensor settings in psensor they often change to some absurd value (e.g max CPU usage = 212%!).

I don't know if this is a factor but my home directory is encrypted.

frankie@Ubuntu:~$ sensors
acpitz-virtual-0
Adapter: Virtual device
temp1:        +27.8°C  (crit = +119.0°C)
temp2:        +29.8°C  (crit = +119.0°C)

coretemp-isa-0000
Adapter: ISA adapter
Physical id 0:  +34.0°C  (high = +80.0°C, crit = +100.0°C)
Core 0:         +18.0°C  (high = +80.0°C, crit = +100.0°C)
Core 1:         +17.0°C  (high = +80.0°C, crit = +100.0°C)
Core 2:         +34.0°C  (high = +80.0°C, crit = +100.0°C)
Core 3:         +19.0°C  (high = +80.0°C, crit = +100.0°C)

asus-isa-0000
Adapter: ISA adapter
cpu_fan:        0 RPM
frankie@Ubuntu:~$ sudo pwmconfig

## pwmconfig revision 6243 (2014-03-20)

This program will search your sensors for pulse width modulation (pwm)
controls, and test each one to see if it controls a fan on
your motherboard. Note that many motherboards do not have pwm
circuitry installed, even if your sensor chip supports pwm.

We will attempt to briefly stop each fan using the pwm controls.
The program will attempt to restore each fan to full speed
after testing. However, it is ** very important ** that you
physically verify that the fans have been to full speed
after the program has completed.

/usr/sbin/pwmconfig: 
There are no pwm-capable sensor modules installed

frankie@Ubuntu:~$ fancontrol
Loading configuration from /etc/fancontrol ...
Error: Can't read configuration file

frankie@Ubuntu:~$ 
ls -l /etc/fan*
ls: cannot access '/etc/fan*': No such file or directory

Since posting this question I have tried to get psensor to recognize the sensors on numerous motherboards on multiple machines running a variety of Ubuntu distros.  Recently built two Ubuntu 18.04 LTS machines, one using an ASUS ROG mobo and the other using an old Gigabyte mobo.  Same problem.  This seems to be a global problem with psensor.  Is there a better app to display this information?

Comment: I see quite a few very similar threads (without solutions).... I'm thinking that perhaps adding a config file to /etc/sensors.d might help.  ASUS party line is that they don't support Linux.... an odd position for a company that manufactures the most expensive and most fully featured mobo out there!

Comment: Been hoping to see a response or two ....  This thread seems to fix the problem I'm having except that the OP reports his issue relating to Dell hardware.  What I need (I think) is similar information on the ASUS M8F mobo.  Considering all the flavors of HW that are out there perhaps a sticky thread might be in order?  http://askubuntu.com/questions/281478/fan-speed-in-ubuntu-pwmconfig-no-pwm-capable-sensor-modules-installed?rq=1