# Water Cooler fan control with Ubuntu 12.04

Tags: 12.04, ati, fan

Phenom X4 965 3.4ghz 
4gb RAM 
ATI Radeon HD 6870 1gb 
Water Cooler Corsair

---

After fresh install of Ubuntu 12.04, my water coller was ever enable and run so fast.
I can't disable or control it.

I try follow this post, but doesn't work: [How to control fan speed?](https://askubuntu.com/questions/22108/how-to-control-fan-speed)

When I run `sudo pwmconfig`, appear that:

```
# pwmconfig revision 5857 (2010-08-22)
This program will search your sensors for pulse width modulation (pwm)
controls, and test each one to see if it controls a fan on
your motherboard. Note that many motherboards do not have pwm
circuitry installed, even if your sensor chip supports pwm.

We will attempt to briefly stop each fan using the pwm controls.
The program will attempt to restore each fan to full speed
after testing. However, it is ** very important ** that you
physically verify that the fans have been to full speed
after the program has completed.

/usr/sbin/pwmconfig: There are no pwm-capable sensor modules installed
```

And when I run `sudo fancontrol`, appear that:

```
Loading configuration from /etc/fancontrol ...
Error: Can't read configuration file
```

Answer (score 1):

I found a solution: installing `fglrx` fixed my problems.