# After switching from Ubuntu to Lubuntu, fan constantly working on maximum

Tags: 13.04, lubuntu, hp

Because my HP 6730s didn't work well on Ubuntu (constant hangs, because of the lack of resources) I changed to Lubuntu. Now everything works fine (in terms of speed), but the cooler constantly is working on maximum. That didn't happen on Ubuntu.

Can you give me any advice as to where to look for some solution, because I can't stand the noise for too long?

Comment: By cooler I'm guessing you mean fan speed? If so I'd suggest you give [This question on fan speed](http://askubuntu.com/questions/22108/how-to-control-fan-speed) a look, could help you out.

Comment: After that look at http://askubuntu.com/questions/285434/is-there-a-power-saving-application-similar-to-jupiter/285681#285681