# Ubuntu 12.10 loud fan noise hp compaq 615

Tags: power-management, software-installation

I am totally new to Linux, i installed it yesterday, since than i my fans are really loud, i did not have this problem on windows.

I saw this post on this site [How to control fan speed?](https://askubuntu.com/questions/22108/how-to-control-fan-speed)

But i am totally lost with it because im a new user to Ubuntu when i arrive to that page i see these

- lucid (utils): utilities to read temperature/voltage/fan sensors 
  1:3.1.2-2: all
- precise (utils): utilities to read temperature/voltage/fan sensors
  [universe]  1:3.3.1-2ubuntu1: all
- quantal (utils): utilities to read temperature/voltage/fan sensors
  [universe]  1:3.3.1-2ubuntu2: all
- raring (utils): utilities to read temperature/voltage/fan sensors
  [universe]  1:3.3.2-2ubuntu1: all
- saucy (utils): utilities to read temperature/voltage/fan sensors
  [universe]  1:3.3.3-1ubuntu1: all
- trusty (utils): utilities to read temperature/voltage/fan sensors
  [universe]  1:3.3.3-1ubuntu1: all

So what is lucid? trusty?  saucy? and other? i thought its some kind if a ubuntu type (sorry for beeing silly here) i checked my ubuntu version it just says Ubuntu 12.10

So which one i need to download? I saw there are terminal commands, im new to that too, will it cause some problem if i just copy and paste?

**PS:**

I saw my graphics card is undetected as well i have a ATI Mobility radeon HD 3200, could that cause the problem too?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

1) Try installing proprietary fglrx drivers in place of xorg. Biggest cause of heat/noise.
2) Try removing TLP and using laptop-mode tools instead.
3) You can use psensor to monitor temperatures and powertop to check power management stats and settings.

Comment: can i install fglrx drivers through softvare  center?

Comment: You can use "Software & Updates" but it has a bug which I reported on launchpad: https://bugs.launchpad.net/unity/+bug/1248255 so better sudo apt-get install fglrx fglrx-pxpress.

Comment: i will mark your answer, for taking the time to selp me, but did everything what you and others offerd, this is the 5th time i get display errors at start up and re-install Ubuntu because it wont let me do anything, for me its just a struggle, still thanks for your help and time

Answer (score 0):

Try installing TLP, its an advanced power management tool, it lowers energy usage and in turn lowers the temperature which tunes down that fan speed.

Detailed instructions for installing this can be found here: http://www.webupd8.org/2013/04/improve-power-usage-battery-life-in.html

Comment: i just installed jupiter but i ill try this, thank you for the reply