# Fan In Lenovo Z580

Tags: lenovo, fancontrol

I am running Ubuntu 13.10 on a Lenovo Z580 and the fan is constantly running.  I tried to follow the steps outlined here:

[How to control fan speed?](https://askubuntu.com/questions/22108/how-to-control-fan-speed)

...but apparently the "fancontrol" doesn't recognize my fan.  I guess the fan is unsupported.

Does anyone have any suggestions as to how I can control the fan behaviour?

Thanks in advance.

Comment: Have you installed the Nividia proprietary drivers yet?

Comment: Not indicated for this laptop has Intel HD 4000 graphics as per http://www.laptopmag.com/review/laptop/lenovo-ideapad-z580.aspx and Lenovo has no drivers for Linux for this model as per http://support.lenovo.com/en_US/research/hints-or-tips/detail.page?&DocID=HT073553 .

Comment: Thanks!  This particular model does not have an nVidia card.  I've been all over the internet looking for a solution to no avail.  Oh well!  At least I don't have to worry about it overheating.  I've been using it for a couple of hours now and it's running at a cool 26 (peaking at 32) degrees Celsius :)

Answer (score -1):

Initially i was having same problem with my dell , So what exactly i did

1.Try to clear your pc, the dust might stopping it from cooling , and fan speed depends on CPU temperature , so try that.

2.Try to update kernel , that might fix your hardware and OS compatibility and functioning schema .

3.Finally try to Update your BIOS from Officially declared BIOS version of your vendor .. that worked for me..

Comment: sorry i just copied my post.