# I'm new to ubuntu and just installed 13.10, and my fan is making continous noise(sony vpce series)

Tags: fancontrol

I'm so grateful if someone help me to solve.

Comment: Check if this helps: http://askubuntu.com/a/46135/169250. It's about controlling fan speed (which of course is why your fan is noisy).

Comment: how to install lm-sensors and fancontrol packages

Comment: You can either look for them in Ubuntu Software Center or type in your terminal (`Ctrl`+`Alt`+`T`): `sudo apt-get update && sudo apt-get install lm-sensors fancontrol`

Comment: Setting up fancontrol (1:3.3.3-1ubuntu1) ...
 * Not starting fancontrol; run pwmconfig first.
Processing triggers for ureadahead ...

Comment: it's showing like this

Comment: It's normal... just follow the instructions in the original link, steps 2-4.

Comment: sudo /etc/init.d/module-init-tools restart
sudo: /etc/init.d/module-init-tools: command not found

Comment: This is outdated... this command should be substituted for this: `sudo service kmod start`.

Comment: possible duplicate of [Fan is always on, CPU usage is rather low and can't find the fan or thermal\_zone proc files](http://askubuntu.com/questions/454501/fan-is-always-on-cpu-usage-is-rather-low-and-cant-find-the-fan-or-thermal-zone)

Answer (score 0):

These might be a little more work than you need to go through. What kind of graphics card (if any) do you have? I have an nvidia card and it was going nuts as soon as I installed Ubuntu 13.10.

Turns out..I was running on the open source video drivers and not the proprietary nvidia drivers. Once I upgraded (Go to Ubuntu Software Center > Edit > Softward Sources > Additional Drivers > you should see a list of possible options) to the proprietary drivers and restarted, my fans went back to normal.