# On ubuntu 14.04.2 сooler spinning too fast

Tags: fancontrol

I used Ubuntu 14.04.1 and everything worked well.Recently I tried to install Ubuntu 14.04.2, but the CPU fan began spinning madly fast.The same occured when I installed ubuntu 15.04.I use a desktop with the asus H61 M-K motherboard and GeForce GT 630 graphics card.Unfortunately, because of this problem I no longer use Ubuntu.I hope you will solve this problem.

Comment: Hopefully this link http://askubuntu.com/questions/425909/how-do-i-control-my-fan-speed will help you for reduce fan speed.