# will ubuntu automatically manage fan speed based on heat like windows

Tags: 14.04, fancontrol, alienware, heat

i've just installed ubuntu 14.04  and i intend to game on it. I'm hoping that Ubuntu manages fan speeds automatically  based on heat if not could u please explain to me how to set my fan speeds to high

Comment: It should, but there have been cases of bad drivers causing problems. See http://askubuntu.com/questions/22108/how-to-control-fan-speed, http://askubuntu.com/questions/425909/how-do-i-control-my-fan-speed.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

That's not a matter of managing by the operating system. There's a thermal sensor in the computer that's operating independent of the OS. You'll notice this if there's something wrong with the heatsink of your CPU. Then the CPU starts to get hot very fast. If it gets too hot it might be damaged but it doesn't because the computer will switch off immediately without even starting the OS. The thermal sensor protects the CPU against overheating and it controls the speed of the fan too. Other components like the videocard might have a similar system.

Comment: OK thank you for answering  did not know if it was controlled by the OS or not

Comment: If you're satisfied with my answer then please click on the grey checkmark in the left margin next to my answer to accept it.

Answer (score 2):

The ACPI spec provides mechanisms for the firmware to describe to the OS how to control the fan speed and measure the temperature, and at what temperature it should change the fan speed, allowing the OS to tweak things as it chooses.  Unfortunately, no vendors that I have seen follow the spec, and instead of leaving control to the OS, they just manage the fan speed with dedicated hardware controllers that lie outside the knowledge of the OS.