# Fan Control on Asus ROG G550JK

Tags: asus, overheating, temperature, sensors, fancontrol

Does anybody here have experience on the G550JK (or similar to this model) with Fancontrol? Currently I have the problem that all methods of getting the fan to control / spin faster (because the notebook is getting hot after some time, especially when gaming) failed.
I followed [this](https://help.ubuntu.com/community/SensorInstallHowto) tutorial:

`sudo sensors-detect` outputted [this](http://pastebin.com/raw.php?i=m0ehNcpJ) (only 'coretemp' was found)

`sudo pwmconfig` outputted

```
luca@luca-G550JK:~$ sudo pwmconfig

pwmconfig revision 6166 (2013-05-01)

This program will search your sensors for pulse width modulation (pwm) controls, and test each one to see if it controls a fan on your motherboard. Note that many motherboards do not have pwm circuitry installed, even if your sensor chip supports pwm.

We will attempt to briefly stop each fan using the pwm controls. The
program will attempt to restore each fan to full speed after testing.
However, it is ** very important ** that you physically verify that
the fans have been to full speed after the program has completed.

/usr/sbin/pwmconfig: There are no fan-capable sensor modules installed
```

Can someone please help me?

Comment: Have you tried [this workaround](http://www.tjansson.dk/2008/10/controlling-fanspeeds-in-linux-on-pwm-motherboards-thinkpads-and-asus-eee-pc/) ?

Comment: @TazD. 
`root@luca-G550JK:~# cat /sys/class/hwmon/hwmon0/device/fan1_input`


`cat: /sys/class/hwmon/hwmon0/device/fan1_input: No such file or directory`

Comment: Asus mobos use something called **Asus ATK-110 ACPI Utility** or so, it should be active when booting the kernel.

Comment: How can I find out if it is active?

Comment: Check your logs in /var/log/boot.log .

Comment: Also 
this: 
         Starting fan speed regulator...
[FAILED] Failed to start fan speed regulator.
See "systemctl status fancontrol.service" for details.

is in the boot.log

Comment: root@luca-G550JK:~# cat /var/log/boot.log  | grep -i ASUS
         Starting Load/Save Screen Backlight Brightness of leds:asus::kbd_backlight...
[  OK  ] Started Load/Save Screen Backlight Brightness of leds:asus::kbd_backlight.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/26867/discussion-between-z3ntu-and-taz-d).

Comment: Similar problem on [this page](http://askubuntu.com/questions/425909/how-do-i-control-my-fan-speed), but this one has the so called **atk0110-acpi-0** present. there is a solution in there too --> use pwmconfig.

Comment: Output of `sudo pwmconfig` is in the original post

Comment: You need that package present on your system, *atk0110-acpi-0* ,  you don't seem to have it. Try booting the kernel with this extra argument next to **quiet splah** -->  *acpi=off*, and see what next.

Comment: If you could still help me, I tried booting with acpi=off , but it hanged with "Loading initial ramdisk..." though it seemed like the fan was spinning faster :) My grub options: GRUB_CMDLINE_LINUX_DEFAULT="quiet splash acpi_enforce_resources=lax acpi_osi="