# Fan Control with 13.10 and ASUS P8Z77-V deluxe motherboard

Tags: 13.10, asus, fan

My supposed quite PC is quiet audible presently.  I have three Silent Wings 2 fans connected to the ASUS P8Z77-V Deluxe motherboard and a Dark Rock 2 CPU Cooler with fan all working nicely and connected to the motherboard keeping temperatures very reasonable but they are spinning too fast and creating a sound I shouldn't be getting as they whirl around.

The BIOS has the fan settings set to 'Silent' mode and in Windows they are, but in Ubuntu they run too fast.

I have been along the lm-sensors and pwmconfig route, as suggested in other posts here and elsewhere but pwmconfig comes back with the message,

> `/usr/sbin/pwmconfig: There are no pwm-capable sensor modules installed`

.

I am uncertain how to resolve.

How can I turn down the fans?
Is it worth investing in an inexpensive PCI fan control that is compatible with Linux?

Comment: See also: https://askubuntu.com/a/1223873/50254

Answer (score 0):

I tried steps which described on the following page, and those work with Ubuntu 15.04.

[How to control fan speed?](https://askubuntu.com/questions/22108/how-to-control-fan-speed)

Answer (score -1):

before you jump into conclusions, try checking your cpu usage. high cpu or gpu usage can also trigger fan. as far as i know, the fans are controlled by bios which is OS independent. so, try checking bios for fan mode.

Comment: No, not all fans are bios controlled, and hw configuration is normally on a (very) safe side. It's one of the difficult spots in Ubuntu, too many moherboard makers do not support directly linux and have to be reverse engineered (I do not if it is the case of this MB, though).

Comment: I tried the fans plugged directly into the Dark Power Pro PSU.  The fans are now running a lot quieter, but still audible.  Sadly I have even less control over them now as I've removed them from BIOS control/monitoring but as that wasn't helping I guess it's a sacrifice worth undertaking for a bit.  I noticed during the process the the fans only have three not four pins, so no PWM support anyway. Doh!  Still, it would be nice to find a software based solution running voltage control through the motherboard which adjusts to demands.