# Ubuntu 14.04 High CPU Temperature but Fans Remain Silent

Tags: 14.04, nvidia, fan, temperature, intel-cpu

I am using Ubuntu 14.04 (3.13.0-32-generic) on my new ASUS n550JK laptop. It has Intel i7 4700HQ CPU and Nvidia GeForce GTX 850M graphics card (I have installed 340.24 driver from `xorg-edgers`).

The thing is that the CPU temperature is about 50°C and the fans are so silent that I almost can't even hear them working. Is this OK or not? If not how can I fix it? If it is possible, I would like to lower the temperature below or around 40°C while only surfing the web.

Here is the output from sensors command while I'm surfing the web:

```
acpitz-virtual-0
Adapter: Virtual device
temp1:        +52.0°C  (crit = +103.0°C)    

coretemp-isa-0000
Adapter: ISA adapter
Physical id 0:  +53.0°C  (high = +84.0°C, crit = +100.0°C)
Core 0:         +50.0°C  (high = +84.0°C, crit = +100.0°C)
Core 1:         +49.0°C  (high = +84.0°C, crit = +100.0°C)
Core 2:         +50.0°C  (high = +84.0°C, crit = +100.0°C)
Core 3:         +50.0°C  (high = +84.0°C, crit = +100.0°C)    

asus-isa-0000
Adapter: ISA adapter
temp1:        +52.0°C
```

Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

Yeah man, 50 is great. Your fans aren't working hard because your temps are optimal. Your battery life must be awesome.

To give you some perspective, my fans run allot when scrolling through something like Tumblr, using Youtube or streaming Cable TV apps but my temps get up to 70 sometimes. I understand your concern but it looks like you are just running a good setup.

To be sure, make sure all of the sensor apps are installed

```
sudo apt-get install lm-sensors hddtemp libsensors4 xsensors fancontrol
```

And if you haven't already run the following command, this might help:

```
sudo sensors-detect
```

The "fancontrol" app does not work on my sensors so I can't tell you much about it sounds like it might be what you are looking for.

To configure fancontrol use this command:

```
sudo pwmconfig
```

and execute

```
sudo service fancontrol start
```

to start it up the first time and after that it should start automatically on boot

see this related post

[How to control fan speed?](https://askubuntu.com/questions/22108/how-to-control-fan-speed)

Comment: Thanks, but after running `sudo pwmconfig` I got this message: `/usr/sbin/pwmconfig: There are no fan-capable sensor modules installed`. Is there any other way to make this work? I can't believe that there are no sensors ?!

Comment: @Kodin You have sensors but the app is not compatible with the ones you have. I had the same issue and so do many others.

Comment: @Kodin This may help but doesn't always work also. http://askubuntu.com/questions/463640/ubuntu-sensors-how-to-decrease-temperatures-threshold?rq=1

Comment: Thanks for your comments, but I haven't managed to get fancontrol to work on my laptop. I have seen around on forums other people having the same problems, but it seems there is no working solution. I appreciate the help.

Comment: @Kodin you might want to look into that CPU temp because 53c seems pretty low to me; it may not be a problem.

Answer (score 0):

upgrade to Ubuntu 16.04.1 LTS.
I faced the same issue of high temprature for more than 2  year of use ubuntu 14 and Asus k52 laptop. with cooler it was ok.
last month I upgraded to Ubuntu 16.04.1 LTS. It's fantastic. Very lite and cool. Temprature droped down more than 10 C. so :upgrade to Ubuntu 16.04.1 LTS.