# My laptop is noisy...fan problem?

Tags: power-management

I have an ASUS laptop that works fine: fast, no overheating etc. My problem is that the fans always run.

I find this very annoying because in a silent room they are really loud

How can I control their speed? Maybe setting a lower fan speed will fix the problem?

I started [here](https://askubuntu.com/a/46135/148451):

- installed `lm-sensors`
- installed `fancontrol`
- ran `sudo sensors-detect`
- this command outputs an error:

  ```
  $ sudo service module-init-tools restart
  module-init-tools: unrecognized service
  ```

Is there any hope to fix these noisy fan sounds?

Also:

```
$ fancontrol 
Loading configuration from /etc/fancontrol ...
Error: Can't read configuration file
```

`$ man fancontrol` says: *For easy configuration, there's a script named pwmconfig(8)
...*

```
$ sudo pwmconfig 
[sudo] password for ionicabizau: 
# pwmconfig revision 6166 (2013-05-01)
This program will search your sensors for pulse width modulation (pwm)
controls, and test each one to see if it controls a fan on
your motherboard. Note that many motherboards do not have pwm
circuitry installed, even if your sensor chip supports pwm.

We will attempt to briefly stop each fan using the pwm controls.
The program will attempt to restore each fan to full speed
after testing. However, it is ** very important ** that you
physically verify that the fans have been to full speed
after the program has completed.

/usr/sbin/pwmconfig: There are no fan-capable sensor modules installed
```

Comment: Did you poke at fancontrol?

Comment: @Braiam I successfully installed it, but I stopped at `sudo sensors-detect` which returns an error.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Those fans are there and triggered at that speed for a reason.  Trying to lower the fan speed just to reduce the noise might actually be harmful to your hardware causing it to overheat and then you are in a bad place!

Sounds like you are driving your CPU a bit ... try reducing the amount of active proceses and the total amount of CPU and then I believe the fan speed will lower.

One note, if your system is dirty or clogged on the inside this could potentially be causing the fan speed to be higher.

Summary, change fan speed realizing the risk for serious hardware damage.

If the fans are noisy, replace them.  This is not a high cost part.

After the fans, the HDD are the next thing to cause noise, afterall that is about the only other thing with moving parts.   In the past, I have had to eventually replace a noisy HD drive due to this.  I was afraid that the disk was going bad and wanted to avoid the pain and agony of a surprise situation.  My guess is that some of the bearings in the drive go out (just like the wheels in your car) and cause this obnoxious noise.

Comment: Actually the noise was produced by the HDD. I replaced it with SSD and suddenly everything is silent. :-) Update your answer and I will mark it.

Comment: ok, I made the modifications.