# How to reduce CPU temperature ?

Tags: ati, overheating, fan

I have Ubuntu 14.04 and an HP Pavilion laptop. When running Windows 7 the CPU is slightly hot but not much. But running Ubuntu however, it is considerably hotter. I installed `tlp` and my GFX card drivers (AMD Catalyst) for embedded APU which is a Radeon 6480G. Since then the temperature has went down to about 60C.

Is there any way to further reduce the temperature? In particular I noticed that in Windows 7 the fan is running more efficient than on Ubuntu. Is there any way to speed up the fan?

Comment: Please tell us which graphic card you are using. It maybe that the graphic card is getting too hot. BTW Did you try what is mentioned in this answer [here](http://askubuntu.com/questions/285434/is-there-a-power-saving-application-similar-to-jupiter/285681#285681) with your tlp? If not please try.

Comment: It is an embedded APU. Radeon 6480G.

Comment: Perhaps this will help http://askubuntu.com/questions/22108/how-to-control-fan-speed

Comment: Sadly no, it says that no controllable fans were detected

Answer (score 0):

I'm astonished that you got your computer down to 60!  I have a pavilion dv7-4263 (radeon 6370/7370) and regularly see temperatures over 70, and occasionally over 80.

A couple of things you will want to bookmark and keep: The GPU in a pavilion will eventually come unsoldered from the main board because of heat effects.  HP wil sell you a new  motherboard, or you [can fix it yourself](http://www.computerrepairtips.net/how-to-reflow-a-laptop-motherboard/).  I've performed this process twice, and although it's time consuming and will evetually fail, it does make the computer work again.

Secondly, there is a thriving market on amazon for laptop cooling pads (built in fans on a little stand for your laptop).  A whole lot of them were designed just for pavilions.

With tlp in place and configured, there is little more that I have found that you can do to make the system run at lower temperatures.  It may help to use the AMD proprietary drivers, but I have not been able to make these run on the HP system under either 14.04 or 12.04.