# Slow Fan Speed in Ubuntu

Tags: fan

I'd like to ask how can I speed up/control my laptop fan speed?
My laptop is always going hotter when running Ubuntu 14.04 than running Windows 8.1.

According to Psensor status, the Core1 & 2 and the Physical ID temperature could reach arround 55-60 Degree Celcius, but the fan speed is just running/spinning arround 93-132 RPM. In Windows 8.1 the temperature is just arround 47-50 Degree Celcius and the fan is running at high speed than Ubuntu.

Is there a way how to speed up my laptop fan speed?
or Is there a way to control my laptop fan speed?

My laptop is Lenovo G400.

Comment: It's something that depends strictly on hardware and drivers. Probably you have too see http://askubuntu.com/questions/22108/how-to-control-fan-speed

Comment: Hi, I've tried fancontrol from the above link but I can't control the fan speed, it still spinning at the same speed

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Sounds like you have the opposite issue with fan speed to what I had. My fans used to run high, constantly. Here is my solution for getting my fan speeds back to normal, from another thread:

> Fan speed is normalized by editing the line
>
> **`GRUB_CMDLINE_LINUX_DEFAULT="quiet splash"`**
>
> in the grub configuration file found at */etc/default/grub* so that it reads
>
> **`GRUB_CMDLINE_LINUX_DEFAULT="quiet splash acpi_osi=!Windows 2012"`**.
>
> Follow these steps to try this solution:
>
> 1. Open a terminal, type
>
>    **sudo gedit /etc/default/grub**,
>
>    and press ENTER
> 2. Enter your login password and press ENTER (the password will not be displayed as you type it)
> 3. Edit the line,
>
>    **`GRUB_CMDLINE_LINUX_DEFAULT="quiet splash"`**
>
>    such that it reads,
>
>    **`GRUB_CMDLINE_LINUX_DEFAULT="quiet splash acpi_osi=!Windows 2012"`**.
> 4. Click "Save", wait a few moments for the file to save, then close the text editor.
> 5. In the terminal, type
>
>    **`sudo update-grub`**
>
>    and hit ENTER
> 6. Finally, shut down your computer. Shut it down completely, so don't "restart" it.
>
> Once you turn your computer back on and select the linux operating system whose grub file you edited earlier, your fans should be working normally. This solution has worked for me on Ubuntu, Linux Mint, Elementary OS, and LXLE on a Dell Inspiron 15R 5520 laptop.

I hope this remedies your issue.

Answer (score 1):

I suggest you use the CPU frequency control indicator to change the operating frequency of the CPU. Set it to `powersave` or `ondemand` or some specific low value.

In a terminal window:

```
sudo apt-get install indicator-cpufreq
```

Now just logout and log in.

Comment: I tried that but I see the temperature still going high even I set it to powersave.

Answer (score 0):

I think this is normal, and the difference is in the two Operating Systems.  Those temps are fine so therefore the fan speed is ok also.