# Overheating (fan problem) in ubuntu 18.04.2. What should I do?

Tags: 18.04, overheating, fan, temperature

I have an ASUS S510UA which came with Windows 10. I replace the HDD with an SSD and added another 8 GB ram memory.

I installed Ubuntu 18.04.2 in parallel and the fan is not working well.

When I am using Windows it never gets hot. However, when I am on Linux, it always gets hot.

I have already installed lm-sensors. When I run `sudo sensors-detect`, this block at the end of this message is what I get.

I tried this:
[Slow Fan Speed in Ubuntu](https://askubuntu.com/questions/524554/slow-fan-speed-in-ubuntu)
But it didn't solve the problem. It just turns on the fan when ubuntu is starting, but the computer still gets hot.

Then I tried installing ACPI, because it was mentioned in another post that I could not find again:
sudo gedit acpi-call-dkms
But it didn't solve it either.

Is there anything else I could try?

Thanks in advance!

```
[sudo] password for note:
# sensors-detect revision 6284 (2015-05-31 14:00:33 +0200)
# System: ASUSTeK COMPUTER INC. X510UAR [1.0] (laptop)
# Kernel: 4.15.0-45-generic x86_64
# Processor: Intel(R) Core(TM) i7-8550U CPU @ 1.80GHz (6/142/10)

This program will help you determine which kernel modules you need
to load to use lm_sensors most effectively. It is generally safe
and recommended to accept the default answers to all questions,
unless you know what you're doing.

Some south bridges, CPUs or memory controllers contain embedded sensors.
Do you want to scan for them? This is totally safe. (YES/no): YES
Module cpuid loaded successfully.
Silicon Integrated Systems SIS5595...                       No
VIA VT82C686 Integrated Sensors...                          No
VIA VT8231 Integrated Sensors...                            No
AMD K8 thermal sensors...                                   No
AMD Family 10h thermal sensors...                           No
AMD Family 11h thermal sensors...                           No
AMD Family 12h and 14h thermal sensors...                   No
AMD Family 15h thermal sensors...                           No
AMD Family 16h thermal sensors...                           No
AMD Family 15h power sensors...                             No
AMD Family 16h power sensors...                             No
Intel digital thermal sensor...                             Success!
    (driver `coretemp')
Intel AMB FB-DIMM thermal sensor...                         No
Intel 5500/5520/X58 thermal sensor...                       No
VIA C7 thermal sensor...                                    No
VIA Nano thermal sensor...                                  No

Some Super I/O chips contain embedded sensors. We have to write to
standard I/O ports to probe them. This is usually safe.
Do you want to scan for Super I/O sensors? (YES/no): YES
Probing for Super-I/O at 0x2e/0x2f
Trying family `National Semiconductor/ITE'...               No
Trying family `SMSC'...                                     No
Trying family `VIA/Winbond/Nuvoton/Fintek'...               No
Trying family `ITE'...                                      No
Probing for Super-I/O at 0x4e/0x4f
Trying family `National Semiconductor/ITE'...               No
Trying family `SMSC'...                                     No
Trying family `VIA/Winbond/Nuvoton/Fintek'...               No
Trying family `ITE'...                                      No

Some hardware monitoring chips are accessible through the ISA I/O ports.
We have to write to arbitrary I/O ports to probe them. This is usually
safe though. Yes, you do have ISA I/O ports even if you do not have any
ISA slots! Do you want to scan the ISA I/O ports? (YES/no): YES
Probing for `National Semiconductor LM78' at 0x290...       No
Probing for `National Semiconductor LM79' at 0x290...       No
Probing for `Winbond W83781D' at 0x290...                   No
Probing for `Winbond W83782D' at 0x290...                   No

Lastly, we can probe the I2C/SMBus adapters for connected hardware
monitoring devices. This is the most risky part, and while it works
reasonably well on most systems, it has been reported to cause trouble
on some systems.
Do you want to probe the I2C/SMBus adapters now? (YES/no): YES
Found unknown SMBus adapter 8086:9d23 at 0000:00:1f.4.
Sorry, no supported PCI bus adapters found.

Next adapter: i915 gmbus dpc (i2c-0)
Do you want to scan it? (yes/NO/selectively): yes

Next adapter: i915 gmbus dpb (i2c-1)
Do you want to scan it? (yes/NO/selectively): yes

Next adapter: i915 gmbus dpd (i2c-2)
Do you want to scan it? (yes/NO/selectively): yes

Next adapter: DPDDC-A (i2c-3)
Do you want to scan it? (yes/NO/selectively): yes

Next adapter: Synopsys DesignWare I2C adapter (i2c-4)
Do you want to scan it? (YES/no/selectively): YES
Adapter doesn't support all probing functions.
Some addresses won't be probed.

Next adapter: Synopsys DesignWare I2C adapter (i2c-5)
Do you want to scan it? (YES/no/selectively): YES
Adapter doesn't support all probing functions.
Some addresses won't be probed.


Now follows a summary of the probes I have just done.
Just press ENTER to continue: 

Driver 'coretemp':
  * Chip `Intel digital thermal sensor' (confidence: 9)

To load everything that is needed, add this to /etc/modules:
#----cut here----
# Chip drivers
coretemp
#----cut here----
If you have some drivers built into your kernel, the list above will
contain too many modules. Skip the appropriate ones!

Do you want to add these lines automatically to /etc/modules? (yes/NO)

#----cut here----
If you have some drivers built into your kernel, the list above will
contain too many modules. Skip the appropriate ones!

Do you want to add these lines automatically to /etc/modules? (yes/NO)
```

Comment: You could try to answer `Y` to the question ...

Comment: I tried it. I just didn't paste the entire thing.

Comment: There's a few other options that I have no experience with:  `i8kutils` (dell fan control) `thinkfan` (claims to run all),  this stuff [https://www.thinkwiki.org/wiki/How_to_control_fan_speed](https://www.thinkwiki.org/wiki/How_to_control_fan_speed), and the BIOS modifiers [http://forum.notebookreview.com/threads/asus-fan-control.660901/](http://forum.notebookreview.com/threads/asus-fan-control.660901/)

Comment: Thank you. But it did not work.
I tried thinkfan, but it didn't work. I am not sure if I used it correctly though.
As the i8utils is for dell, and the other link was doing some uncertain stuff to the BIOS, I thought that it is better not to try, because it may brick the computer, as many people mentioned... 
Thanks though.

Answer (score 0):

Part of the answer lies in how you handled the recommended modification to your modules, suggested by `sudo sensors-detect`.  That program is asking you to install the `coretemp` module, and it defaults to "No".  The second half is in using the Sensors output to run the Fancontrol module.

1st, lets add the module to your system

```
sudo cp /etc/modules /etc/modules.bak
sudo nano /etc/modules
```

Scroll to the bottom, add the line `coretemp` if it is not there, and press <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>o</kbd> to output the file and <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>x</kbd> to exit the editor

Now you need to install the program `fancontrol`, configure the pwm fan control units, and ties them into the sensor package:

```
sudo apt install fancontrol
sudo pwmconfig
```

`pwmconfig` will walk through the process of testing the fan for it's ability to control the fans, and allow you to set custom levels of temperature for turning the fans on and off.  Then you need to set the output of sensors for Fancontrol.

```
sudo sensors -s
```

Finally, enable and start the Fancontrol service

```
sudo systemctl enable fancontrol
sudo systemctl start fancontrol
```

Finally, you can monitor both the temperature sensors and the fan speed at the terminal with `sensors` command.  To continuously you can `watch sensors`, and for more advanced temperature monitoring you could use a program such as `psensor`

Comment: Hi, Charles thanks for your answer, but it did not work.
When I ran `sudo pwmconfig` this was the output:

   `# pwmconfig revision 6243 (2014-03-20)`
    `This program will search your sensors for pulse width modulation (pwm)`
   `controls, and test each one to see if it controls a fan on`
   `your motherboard. Note that many motherboards do not have pwm`
    `circuitry installed, even if your sensor chip supports pwm.`
    
    (My answer continues in the next comment)

Comment: `We will attempt to briefly stop each fan using the pwm controls.`
    `The program will attempt to restore each fan to full speed`
   `after testing. However, it is ** very important ** that you`
    `physically verify that the fans have been to full speed`
    `after the program has completed.`
    
    **`/usr/sbin/pwmconfig: There are no pwm-capable sensor modules installed`**


Is there anything else I should try? I googled this, but it seems that people recommend installing lm-sensors, and this is already installed in mine.

Comment: @RFC You *could* try to use the `coretemp` module as described at the end of your `sensors-detect` run, but I suspect that will not assist with the fan control issue.  Do you have `Tlp` or other power management software installed?

Comment: @RFC  `sudo modeprobe coretemp` and then re-run `sudo pwmcontrol` would test the utility of the coretemp module.

Comment: Hi Charles, I had added the `coretemp` when I ran `lm-sensors`. I don't have `Tlp` installed. The `pwmcontrol` command was not found, and I didn't find anything on google to sort that out. It is curious that fan problems seem to be quite common in Ubuntu, and there is not a lot of good solutions for that.

Comment: I'm sorry - I was working on something else at the same time, and the program I meant for you was `pwmconfig`, but I don't think that having coretemp installed will add the pwm controls.  Tlp is just a general all-around good solution to managing laptop power (and heat), and easy to configure.  The problems seem centered around thinkpad (lenovo) and Asus - sorry!

Comment: It did not work. It says:
`/usr/sbin/pwmconfig: There are no pwm-capable sensor modules installed`
Then I installed Tlp. Following the instructions on this page https://wiki.archlinux.org/index.php/Fan_speed_control#Asus_laptops, I tried running the `echo 255 > /sys/devices/platform/asus-nb-wmi/hwmon/hwmon3/pwm1`, but even after sudo su, it still says `Permission denied`.
Do you have any other ideas?

Comment: @RFC Yes!  sending echo via sudo is troublesome.  You need to tee the output:  `echo 255  | sudo tee /sys/devices/platform/asus-nb-wmi/hwmon/hwmon3/pwm1` will set the value 255 in the file.

Comment: Still says `tee: /sys/devices/platform/asus-nb-wmi/hwmon/hwmon3/pwm1: Permission denied 255`. FYI, within hwmon3 dir there is: `device`, `name`, `power`, `subsystem`, and `uevent`. There is no pwm1 file.

Comment: Ah.  If there is not pwm1 file...

Comment: Is there a website I can tell ubuntu developers about this issue? Because I won't be able to use Ubuntu anymore, if there is no solution to this.

Comment: @RFC Actually I think it's more of a linux in general issue, but you might ask at [meta] where to put feature requests.

Answer (score 0):

I got the same error while trying to run `sudo pwmconfig`. I found that the main cause of the problem was over-clocking of the CPU. Disabling turbo boost from BIOS will reduce the problem to some extent. But the CPU frequency will still be at maximum. There is a temporary work around for this by manually changing the CPU frequency governor.

Disable ondemand for CPU governor.

```
sudo systemctl disable ondemand
```

Install linux kernel tools and change the frequency governor to powersave.

```
sudo apt-get install -y linux-tools-$(uname -r)
sudo cpupower frequency-set --governor powersave
```

This should resolve your issues until there is an official update to handle this. You can find a more detailed explanation of the solution here: [Ubuntu 18.04 Overheating Problem.](https://sphanit.github.io/blog/u18heatfix)

Answer (score 0):

I would recommend installing `thermald` (it's meant for Intel CPUs) to solve this. It uses fan control, CPU's power states and idle commands to control temperature, so should be more efficient than just fan control. And remove other conflicting solutions. 'on demand' CPU governor should be fine.

And sure you need `coretemp` module loaded for it to work. Without sensors readings it's useless.