# sensors-detect not showing motherboard info

Tags: 14.04, fan, temperature, sensors, lm-sensors

why is sensors-detect giving only coretemp as an output without the motherboard information, trying to control cpu gpu fans Ubuntu 14.04

output of sensors detect:

## sensors-detect revision 6170 (2013-05-20 21:25:22 +0200)

## System: Micro-Star International Co., Ltd. GS63VR 6RF [REV:1.0] (laptop)

## Board: Micro-Star International Co., Ltd. MS-16K2

This program will help you determine which kernel modules you need
to load to use lm_sensors most effectively. It is generally safe
and recommended to accept the default answers to all questions,
unless you know what you're doing.

Some south bridges, CPUs or memory controllers contain embedded sensors.
Do you want to scan for them? This is totally safe. (YES/no): y
Module cpuid loaded successfully.
Silicon Integrated Systems SIS5595...                       No
VIA VT82C686 Integrated Sensors...                          No
VIA VT8231 Integrated Sensors...                            No
AMD K8 thermal sensors...                                   No
AMD Family 10h thermal sensors...                           No
AMD Family 11h thermal sensors...                           No
AMD Family 12h and 14h thermal sensors...                   No
AMD Family 15h thermal sensors...                           No
AMD Family 15h power sensors...                             No
AMD Family 16h power sensors...                             No
Intel digital thermal sensor...                             Success!
    (driver `coretemp')
Intel AMB FB-DIMM thermal sensor...                         No
VIA C7 thermal sensor...                                    No
VIA Nano thermal sensor...                                  No

Some Super I/O chips contain embedded sensors. We have to write to
standard I/O ports to probe them. This is usually safe.
Do you want to scan for Super I/O sensors? (YES/no): y
Probing for Super-I/O at 0x2e/0x2f
Trying family `National Semiconductor/ITE'...               No
Trying family`SMSC'...                                     No
Trying family `VIA/Winbond/Nuvoton/Fintek'...               No
Trying family`ITE'...                                      No
Probing for Super-I/O at 0x4e/0x4f
Trying family `National Semiconductor/ITE'...               No
Trying family`SMSC'...                                     No
Trying family `VIA/Winbond/Nuvoton/Fintek'...               No
Trying family`ITE'...                                      No

Some hardware monitoring chips are accessible through the ISA I/O ports.
We have to write to arbitrary I/O ports to probe them. This is usually
safe though. Yes, you do have ISA I/O ports even if you do not have any
ISA slots! Do you want to scan the ISA I/O ports? (YES/no): y
Probing for `National Semiconductor LM78' at 0x290...       No
Probing for`National Semiconductor LM79' at 0x290...       No
Probing for `Winbond W83781D' at 0x290...                   No
Probing for`Winbond W83782D' at 0x290...                   No

Lastly, we can probe the I2C/SMBus adapters for connected hardware
monitoring devices. This is the most risky part, and while it works
reasonably well on most systems, it has been reported to cause trouble
on some systems.
Do you want to probe the I2C/SMBus adapters now? (YES/no): y
Found unknown SMBus adapter 8086:a123 at 0000:00:1f.4.
Sorry, no supported PCI bus adapters found.

Next adapter: i915 gmbus dpc (i2c-0)
Do you want to scan it? (yes/NO/selectively): y

Next adapter: i915 gmbus dpb (i2c-1)
Do you want to scan it? (yes/NO/selectively): y

Next adapter: i915 gmbus dpd (i2c-2)
Do you want to scan it? (yes/NO/selectively): y
Client found at address 0x19
Probing for `Analog Devices ADM1021'...                     No
Probing for`Analog Devices ADM1021A/ADM1023'...            No
Probing for `Maxim MAX1617'...                              No
Probing for`Maxim MAX1617A'...                             No
Probing for `Maxim MAX1668'...                              No
Probing for`Maxim MAX1805'...                              No
Probing for `Maxim MAX1989'...                              No
Probing for`Maxim MAX6655/MAX6656'...                      No
Probing for `TI THMC10'...                                  No
Probing for`National Semiconductor LM84'...                No
Probing for `Genesys Logic GL523SM'...                      No
Probing for`Onsemi MC1066'...                              No
Probing for `Maxim MAX1618'...                              No
Probing for`Maxim MAX1619'...                              No
Probing for `National Semiconductor LM82/LM83'...           No
Probing for`Maxim MAX6654'...                              No
Probing for `Maxim MAX6690'...                              No
Probing for`Maxim MAX6680/MAX6681'...                      No
Probing for `Maxim MAX6695/MAX6696'...                      No
Probing for`Texas Instruments AMC6821'...                  No
Probing for `National Semiconductor LM95231'...             No
Probing for`National Semiconductor LM95241'...             No
Probing for `National Semiconductor LM95245'...             No
Probing for`ST STTS424'...                                 No
Probing for `ST STTS424E'...                                No
Probing for`ST STTS2002'...                                No
Probing for `ST STTS3000'...                                No
Probing for`NXP SE97/SE97B'...                             No
Probing for `NXP SE98'...                                   No
Probing for`Analog Devices ADT7408'...                     No
Probing for `IDT TS3000/TSE2002'...                         No
Probing for`Maxim MAX6604'...                              No
Probing for `Microchip MCP9804'...                          No
Probing for`Microchip MCP98242'...                         No
Probing for `Microchip MCP98243'...                         No
Probing for`Microchip MCP98244'...                         No
Probing for `Microchip MCP9843'...                          No
Probing for`ON CAT6095/CAT34TS02'...                       No
Probing for `Atmel AT30TS00'...                             No
Client found at address 0x1c
Probing for`Texas Instruments TMP421'...                   No
Probing for `SMSC EMC1072'...                               No
Probing for`SMSC EMC1073'...                               No
Probing for `SMSC EMC1074'...                               No
Probing for`ST STTS424'...                                 No
Probing for `ST STTS424E'...                                No
Probing for`ST STTS2002'...                                No
Probing for `ST STTS3000'...                                No
Probing for`NXP SE97/SE97B'...                             No
Probing for `NXP SE98'...                                   No
Probing for`Analog Devices ADT7408'...                     No
Probing for `IDT TS3000/TSE2002'...                         No
Probing for`Maxim MAX6604'...                              No
Probing for `Microchip MCP9804'...                          No
Probing for`Microchip MCP98242'...                         No
Probing for `Microchip MCP98243'...                         No
Probing for`Microchip MCP98244'...                         No
Probing for `Microchip MCP9843'...                          No
Probing for`ON CAT6095/CAT34TS02'...                       No
Probing for `Atmel AT30TS00'...                             No
Client found at address 0x1f
Probing for`Texas Instruments TMP421'...                   No
Probing for `ST STTS424'...                                 No
Probing for`ST STTS424E'...                                No
Probing for `ST STTS2002'...                                No
Probing for`ST STTS3000'...                                No
Probing for `NXP SE97/SE97B'...                             No
Probing for`NXP SE98'...                                   No
Probing for `Analog Devices ADT7408'...                     No
Probing for`IDT TS3000/TSE2002'...                         No
Probing for `Maxim MAX6604'...                              No
Probing for`Microchip MCP9804'...                          No
Probing for `Microchip MCP98242'...                         No
Probing for`Microchip MCP98243'...                         No
Probing for `Microchip MCP98244'...                         No
Probing for`Microchip MCP9843'...                          No
Probing for `ON CAT6095/CAT34TS02'...                       No
Probing for`Atmel AT30TS00'...                             No
Client found at address 0x29
Probing for `National Semiconductor LM78'...                No
Probing for`National Semiconductor LM79'...                No
Probing for `National Semiconductor LM80'...                No
Probing for`National Semiconductor LM96080'...             No
Probing for `Winbond W83781D'...                            No
Probing for`Winbond W83782D'...                            No
Probing for `Winbond W83627HF'...                           No
Probing for`Winbond W83627EHF'...                          No
Probing for `Winbond W83627DHG/W83667HG/W83677HG'...        No
Probing for`Asus AS99127F (rev.1)'...                      No
Probing for `Asus AS99127F (rev.2)'...                      No
Probing for`Asus ASB100 Bach'...                           No
Probing for `Analog Devices ADM1021'...                     No
Probing for`Analog Devices ADM1021A/ADM1023'...            No
Probing for `Maxim MAX1617'...                              No
Probing for`Maxim MAX1617A'...                             No
Probing for `Maxim MAX1668'...                              No
Probing for`Maxim MAX1805'...                              No
Probing for `Maxim MAX1989'...                              No
Probing for`Maxim MAX6655/MAX6656'...                      No
Probing for `TI THMC10'...                                  No
Probing for`National Semiconductor LM84'...                No
Probing for `Genesys Logic GL523SM'...                      No
Probing for`Onsemi MC1066'...                              No
Probing for `Maxim MAX1618'...                              No
Probing for`Maxim MAX1619'...                              No
Probing for `National Semiconductor LM82/LM83'...           No
Probing for`Maxim MAX6654'...                              No
Probing for `Maxim MAX6690'...                              No
Probing for`Maxim MAX6680/MAX6681'...                      No
Probing for `Maxim MAX6695/MAX6696'...                      No
Probing for`National Semiconductor LM95245'...             No
Probing for `Analog Devices ADM1029'...                     No
Probing for`ITE IT8712F'...                                No
Probing for `SMSC EMC1402'...                               No
Probing for`SMSC EMC1403'...                               No
Probing for `SMSC EMC1404'...                               No
Client found at address 0x2b
Probing for`National Semiconductor LM78'...                No
Probing for `National Semiconductor LM79'...                No
Probing for`National Semiconductor LM80'...                No
Probing for `National Semiconductor LM96080'...             No
Probing for`Winbond W83781D'...                            No
Probing for `Winbond W83782D'...                            No
Probing for`Winbond W83627HF'...                           No
Probing for `Winbond W83627EHF'...                          No
Probing for`Winbond W83627DHG/W83667HG/W83677HG'...        No
Probing for `Asus AS99127F (rev.1)'...                      No
Probing for`Asus AS99127F (rev.2)'...                      No
Probing for `Asus ASB100 Bach'...                           No
Probing for`Analog Devices ADM1021'...                     No
Probing for `Analog Devices ADM1021A/ADM1023'...            No
Probing for`Maxim MAX1617'...                              No
Probing for `Maxim MAX1617A'...                             No
Probing for`Maxim MAX1668'...                              No
Probing for `Maxim MAX1805'...                              No
Probing for`Maxim MAX1989'...                              No
Probing for `Maxim MAX6655/MAX6656'...                      No
Probing for`TI THMC10'...                                  No
Probing for `National Semiconductor LM84'...                No
Probing for`Genesys Logic GL523SM'...                      No
Probing for `Onsemi MC1066'...                              No
Probing for`Maxim MAX1618'...                              No
Probing for `Maxim MAX1619'...                              No
Probing for`National Semiconductor LM82/LM83'...           No
Probing for `Maxim MAX6654'...                              No
Probing for`Maxim MAX6690'...                              No
Probing for `Maxim MAX6680/MAX6681'...                      No
Probing for`Maxim MAX6695/MAX6696'...                      No
Probing for `National Semiconductor LM95231'...             No
Probing for`National Semiconductor LM95241'...             No
Probing for `Analog Devices ADM1029'...                     No
Probing for`ITE IT8712F'...                                No
Client found at address 0x49
Probing for `National Semiconductor LM75'...                No
Probing for`National Semiconductor LM75A'...               No
Probing for `Dallas Semiconductor DS75'...                  No
Probing for`National Semiconductor LM77'...                No
Probing for `Analog Devices ADT7410/ADT7420'...             No
Probing for`Maxim MAX6642'...                              No
Probing for `National Semiconductor LM73'...                No
Probing for`National Semiconductor LM92'...                No
Probing for `National Semiconductor LM76'...                No
Probing for`Maxim MAX6633/MAX6634/MAX6635'...              No
Probing for `NXP/Philips SA56004'...                        No
Probing for`SMSC EMC1023'...                               No
Probing for `SMSC EMC1043'...                               No
Probing for`SMSC EMC1053'...                               No
Probing for `SMSC EMC1063'...                               No
Client found at address 0x4d
Probing for`National Semiconductor LM75'...                No
Probing for `National Semiconductor LM75A'...               No
Probing for`Dallas Semiconductor DS75'...                  No
Probing for `Analog Devices ADM1021'...                     No
Probing for`Analog Devices ADM1021A/ADM1023'...            No
Probing for `Global Mixed-mode Technology G781'...          No
Probing for`Maxim MAX1617'...                              No
Probing for `Maxim MAX1617A'...                             No
Probing for`Maxim MAX1668'...                              No
Probing for `Maxim MAX1805'...                              No
Probing for`Maxim MAX1989'...                              No
Probing for `Maxim MAX6642'...                              No
Probing for`Maxim MAX6655/MAX6656'...                      No
Probing for `TI THMC10'...                                  No
Probing for`National Semiconductor LM84'...                No
Probing for `Genesys Logic GL523SM'...                      No
Probing for`Onsemi MC1066'...                              No
Probing for `Maxim MAX1618'...                              No
Probing for`Maxim MAX1619'...                              No
Probing for `National Semiconductor LM82/LM83'...           No
Probing for`National Semiconductor LM89/LM99'...           No
Probing for `Analog Devices ADM1032'...                     No
Probing for`Maxim MAX6654'...                              No
Probing for `Maxim MAX6690'...                              No
Probing for`Maxim MAX6659'...                              No
Probing for `Maxim MAX6646'...                              No
Probing for`Maxim MAX6680/MAX6681'...                      No
Probing for `Maxim MAX6695/MAX6696'...                      No
Probing for`Texas Instruments TMP411'...                   No
Probing for `Texas Instruments TMP421'...                   No
Probing for`Texas Instruments TMP422'...                   No
Probing for `Texas Instruments TMP423'...                   No
Probing for`Texas Instruments TMP431'...                   No
Probing for `Texas Instruments TMP432'...                   No
Probing for`Texas Instruments AMC6821'...                  No
Probing for `National Semiconductor LM95234'...             No
Probing for`National Semiconductor LM95245'...             No
Probing for `National Semiconductor LM73'...                No
Probing for`Maxim MAX6633/MAX6634/MAX6635'...              No
Probing for `Analog Devices ADT7461'...                     No
Probing for`Analog Devices ADT7461A, ON Semiconductor NCT1008'... No
Probing for `NXP/Philips SA56004'...                        No
Probing for`Fintek F75384S/M'...                           No
Probing for `SMSC EMC1002'...                               No
Probing for`SMSC EMC1023'...                               No
Probing for `SMSC EMC1033'...                               No
Probing for`SMSC EMC1043'...                               No
Probing for `SMSC EMC1046'...                               No
Probing for`SMSC EMC1053'...                               No
Probing for `SMSC EMC1063'...                               No
Probing for`SMSC EMC1402'...                               No
Probing for `SMSC EMC1403'...                               No
Probing for`SMSC EMC1404'...                               No
Client found at address 0x77
Probing for `Asus Mozart-2'...                              No

Next adapter: DPDDC-A (i2c-3)
Do you want to scan it? (YES/no/selectively): y
Client found at address 0x50
Probing for `Analog Devices ADM1033'...                     No
Probing for`Analog Devices ADM1034'...                     No
Probing for `SPD EEPROM'...                                 No
Probing for`EDID EEPROM'...                                Yes
    (confidence 8, not a hardware monitoring chip)

Next adapter: DPDDC-C (i2c-4)
Do you want to scan it? (YES/no/selectively): y

Now follows a summary of the probes I have just done.
Just press ENTER to continue:

Driver `coretemp':
  * Chip`Intel digital thermal sensor' (confidence: 9)

To load everything that is needed, add this to /etc/modules:

## ----cut here----

## Chip drivers

coretemp

## ----cut here----

If you have some drivers built into your kernel, the list above will
contain too many modules. Skip the appropriate ones!

My output at the bottom:

https://i.stack.imgur.com/HYUwg.png

Tutorial output: 
[http://imgur.com/gallery/LJcBrUb](https://imgur.com/gallery/LJcBrUb)

The line of w83627ehf is missing from the output of sensors-detect on my PC

Comment: Copy and paste the SuperIO test near the top, the screenshot omits that.

Comment: 'sensors-detect' is only part of the steps to a solution for running the fans - this program is telling you that you should install the module 'coretemp'.  Please see [https://askubuntu.com/a/1123221/283721](https://askubuntu.com/a/1123221/283721)

Comment: @rtaft how do I do a SuperIO test ?

Comment: @CharlesGreen nah I added the coretemp to modules but the problem there should another text under the coretemp in the output of sensors-detect, I'll the image from the tutorial to the question

Comment: `sensors-detect` is a series of tests.  The second test is a Super IO test.  Your screenshot cuts off the beginning of `sensors-detect` so we can't see the Super IO test.  Copy and paste the output from that part of the test.  Also paste the very beginning where it has 'Board', 'System', etc.

Comment: @rtaft okay so I added the full output of sensors-detect above

Comment: And this is Ubuntu 14?  This is an MSI laptop?  You might have luck with Ubuntu 18 or 19, but I doubt 14 is going to have the drivers for it.

Comment: @rtaft ahhh I see, unfortunately i need to mirror my LAB in ubuntu and ros distribution which are respectively 14.04 and indigo, I better invest in in a bottom fan tray then

Comment: you might be able to get it working with thinkfan, that is more geared towards laptops.