# How to Control FanSpeed on hp envy 15

Tags: 14.04, hp, overheating, fan

my computer is prone to over-heating and so I'm trying to control the fan speeds. I've researched a little and I'm blocked [How to control fan speed?](https://askubuntu.com/questions/22108/how-to-control-fan-speed) and then installed `lm-sensors`and `fan control`.

I'm now trying to configure lm-sensors to no avail. In terminal I typed `sudo sensors-detect` and answer YES to all YES/no questions. Installed modules with   `sudo /etc/init.d/kmod start`. Now when I type `sudo pwmconfig`
I get this output

```
     /usr/sbin/pwmconfig: There are no pwm-capable sensor modules installed
```

The way I tried to fixed this is to edit /etc/default/grub to add `acpi_enforce_resources=lax` to the `GRUB_CMDLINE_LINUX_DEFAULT` and then perform a grub update. I'm still having the same issue. This is the output of the `sensors` command.

```
acpitz-virtual-0
Adapter: Virtual device
temp1:        +50.0°C  

coretemp-isa-0000
Adapter: ISA adapter
Physical id 0:  +49.0°C  (high = +84.0°C, crit = +100.0°C)
Core 0:         +48.0°C  (high = +84.0°C, crit = +100.0°C)
Core 1:         +45.0°C  (high = +84.0°C, crit = +100.0°C)
Core 2:         +46.0°C  (high = +84.0°C, crit = +100.0°C)
Core 3:         +44.0°C  (high = +84.0°C, crit = +100.0°C)
```

Can anyone help me? Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

It appears the  fans inside the computer are not PWM or Pulse-width modulation.

Common cooling fans used in computers use standardized connectors with two to four pins.

PWM use a 4 pin connector and can be controlled by software.

The first two pins are always used to deliver power to the fan motor.

3 pin connectors don't have PWM 3-pin fan speed is controlled by voltage.

Comment: Is there nothing to do?

Comment: Is there an  always on option in the bios? Maybe an external laptop cooling pad.Fans become less affective when full of dust.

Comment: Yes there is that option. How is HP controlling fan speed on windows if it is not pwm?