# Enable fan control on ubuntu gnome and macbook pro

Tags: unity, gnome, fan, macbook-pro

I come here after spending 3 good hours trying to make fan control work on a macbook pro and ubuntu gnome.

Some time before, I installed ubuntu unity on this same computer and fan control began immediately after installing macfanctld, nothing more.

I then wanted to have a full gnome experience, and installed ubuntu gnome 15.10 instead.

Now, no matter what daemon I install fan control do not want to activate. I tried macfanctld, mbpfan and even fancontrol which is not really supposed to work for macbook pro's. I went through the process of downloading applesmc dkms package which is not maintained anymore. It's PPA is not working with Wily and I had to install it by hand.

So I wonder what I missed, why fan control worked just after installing one package in ubuntu unity, and why with ubuntu gnome it wont activate at all ?

If someone is able to help me on this situation, I would be really grateful.

UPDATE : Macfanctld reads in fact only the minimum speed for the fans : I change this value, macfanctld actually changes the fans rotation. BUT I managed to have it behave correctly (i.e: control fans speed depending on sensors reads) under ubuntu unity, so something must be missing in my configuration.

Comment: I know this thread is old, but i still got this to work... http://askubuntu.com/questions/22108/how-to-control-fan-speed

Comment: Thank you for your feedback. In my case, I missed the hddtemp package. After installing it fan control was working as it should.