# How to control AMD Radeon fan speed

Tags: radeon

In Linux 4.0 the SMC fan speed control for AMD Radeons has been introduced. I have Gigabyte Windforce Radeon 7870. Booting Ubuntu with kernel 4.0+ helps a little, but the fans are still very loud. Can I customize the speed of the fans, just like AMD Overdrive feature in Catalyst?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How to control fan speed?](http://askubuntu.com/questions/22108/how-to-control-fan-speed)

Comment: Thanks, but my question is not a duplicate of above post, which covers CPU fan speed. My question is about AMD graphic card fan speed control with newest version of open source _radeon_ driver.

Comment: @Kris are you certain? fancontrol controls any fan which lmsensors can find that supports PWM. It's not just for cpu fans.

Comment: @ElderGeek - thanks for the tip. I will try that out.