# How can I turn my Fan on full speed all the time?

Tags: fancontrol

How can I make my laptop fan speed be full all the time? 
Toshiba Satellite

Answer (score 2):

Most modern laptops have fancontrol settings in their BIOS. This is the simplest way of controlling your fan speed and there may be an option to have the fan at full speed all the time.

If not you could install 'lm-sensors' and 'fancontrol'. There is an excellent set of instructions for doing so [here](https://askubuntu.com/questions/22108/how-to-control-fan-speed).

Then configure 'fancontrol' to have the fans running at full speed by setting MAXTEMP to a low temperature like 30.

A more interesting question is why do you want the fans running at full speed? If your laptop is overheating check that the fan and air-vents are not choked with dust. If you don’t want to open up your laptop it is safe to use the nozzle of an ordinary household vacuum cleaner to clean the vents.

Comment: This method might drain the battery faster.

Comment: For example in my stupid laptop it keeps going low and high constantly which is more annoying than having it to run always at high speed.

Answer (score 1):

You cannot control the fan settings/speed from the computer, however this might be able to be controlled by the BIOS, but please check.

If you are having overheating issues, disassemble the laptop, check for dust on the fans and if necessary, add some thermal paste to the cpu and fans **WARNING: THIS MIGHT VOID YOUR WARRANTY. I RECOMMEND GOING TO YOUR ORIGINAL SHOP WHERE YOU PURCHASED THE LAPTOP TO DO IT FOR YOU.**