# Acer ES1-311 no fan control, fan stops completely after resume

Tags: acer, fan, fancontrol, resume

- **Setup:** Acer ES1-311 brand new, latest BIOS V1.11
- **Tested:** Ubuntu 14.04 x64, Xubuntu 16.04 x64
- **Current kernel**: 4.4.0-16-generic
- **Issue:** The fan just runs, there is no temperature or load based
  throttling.
- **Problem:** Suspend system and resume, fan runs on 100% for a second and
  then completely stops leaving the system without any cooling.

I thought I give 'acerhdf' a try, but a modprobe fails:

```
acerhdf: unkown (unsupported) BIOS version Aver/Aspire ES1-311/V1.11, please report, aborting!
```

I also tried to get [NBFC](https://github.com/hirschmann/nbfc) running with mono, no luck, couldn't get it to compile.

Also sensors/pwmconfig did not work.
`/usr/sbin/pwmconfig: There are no pwm-capable sensor modules installed`

So is there a kernel-bug resulting in the fan to stop working, or is there any tool to manually/automatically control my machines fan?

Comment: Quick update, same behaivior with 4.4.0-18-generic

Comment: This issue might exist on all the ES1 models. There's already a bug filed on launchpad, and not yet solved. Maybe you can upvote this ticket to get it solved quickly. https://bugs.launchpad.net/ubuntu/+source/linux/+bug/1560473. This bug has also been reported by AU user Ming-Hung Tsai.

Answer (score 0):

NBFC on Linux is experimental (as stated on [GitHub NBFC homepage](https://github.com/hirschmann/nbfc)). Playing around with acerhdf looks even more difficult.

If your BIOS supports supports fan control enabling this and removing any fan control software you have installed is the safest way of getting effective fan control.

If the BIOS does not feature fan control (most modern laptops BIOS do), then you need to get lm-sensors and fancontrol working. There is an excellent set of instructions for doing this [here](https://askubuntu.com/questions/22108/how-to-control-fan-speed)

Comment: Sadly it seems acer did their best not to support APCI control of the fan. I forgot to mention that sensors/pwmconfig was the first option I tried.
`/usr/sbin/pwmconfig: There are no pwm-capable sensor modules installed`  - I will update my initial post.

Answer (score 0):

This may be somehow connected to the wrong temperature reading after the resume.
After the resume, sensors command shows this

```
acpitz-virtual-0
Adapter: Virtual device
temp1:        +26.8°C  (crit = +105.0°C)

coretemp-isa-0000
Adapter: ISA adapter
Core 0:       +47.0°C  (high = +105.0°C, crit = +105.0°C)
Core 1:       +47.0°C  (high = +105.0°C, crit = +105.0°C)
```

the temp1 never changes and stays the same at +26.8 regardless of the cpu cores temperature which indeed changes with the load.
If the fan control depends on that temperature reading, that may be the reason that the fan never kicks in.