# Fan running at maximum speed on Asus UX32A since last update on Ubuntu 14.04

Tags: 14.04, asus, fan, fancontrol, noise

Have been using Ubuntu 14.04 for a while now, but am still not an advanced user.

After one of the recent updates to the OS, the fan for my laptop runs at abnormally high speeds for prolonged periods. It occasionally slows down briefly (less than 10 seconds) and then speeds up again. The laptop is not overheating, but the issue persists nonetheless, and is very loud and annoying.

I had a similar problem a few months ago, and could not find a solution at the time. One of the updates solved the issue, so I had not thought about it since then.

I found some solutions which involve editing the grub config files, but these were a couple of years old. I was wondering whether there are any newer solutions? I have also found mentions of using lmsensors or fancontrol, but have not tried those yet.

Since the problem has returned it is very annoying as the fan runs at full speed as long as the laptop is powered on. I would appreciate any help in solving this! I may need simplified instructions though, as I am still getting to grips with handling Linux.

Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 2):

You can try to install (or check if it is already installed) `thermald`. It is a daemon that prevent your PC from overheating. To install run the following command:

```
sudo apt-get install thermald
```

I also suggest to enable *Intel P-State* frequency governor that manage how your CPU change working frequency. To do this edit grub configuration file

```
sudo nano /etc/default/grub
```

and add `intel_pstate=enable` to the following line as showed below

```
GRUB_CMDLINE_LINUX_DEFAULT="quiet splash intel_pstate=enable"
```

Now you have to run

```
sudo update-grub
```

to apply changes and then reboot your system to start *Intel P-state* driver.

If this solution is not enough or you want finer fan control you can read this [post](https://askubuntu.com/questions/22108/how-to-control-fan-speed) where you can find a briefly explanation about `lm-sensors` (*cpu sensors monitor*) and `fancontrol` (*let you manage fan settings*) programs.

I hope this will help you.