# Ubuntu 16.04, how to get my GPU temp and fan speed?

Tags: drivers, fan, temperature

On Ubuntu 14.04 I got used to run during the boot process a python script for conky to read my GPU temperature and then change my FAN speed according to the temperature. This is the script:

```
# 
# python /home/ibart/.scripts/ventola_ati.py
#

import os
import time

minTemp = 45.00
maxTemp = 70.00
minSpeed = 10
maxSpeed = 90
updateInterval = 3
fanSpeed = 25

while True:

    f = os.popen('aticonfig --od-gettemperature | grep "Sensor 0" | cut -c43-47')
    currentTemp = eval(str(f.readlines())[2:7])

    if currentTemp > maxTemp:
        if fanSpeed < maxSpeed:
            fanSpeed = fanSpeed + 1
    if currentTemp < minTemp:
        if fanSpeed > minSpeed:
            fanSpeed = fanSpeed - 1

    os.system('aticonfig --pplib-cmd "set fanspeed 0 ' + str(fanSpeed) + '"')

    print fanSpeed
    print currentTemp
    time.sleep(updateInterval)
```

What now that Ubuntu dropped the official drivers for my card, an old and fancy HD5770?

Thanks.

edit. On 16.04 `sensors` detects it. Thanks Luca.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Please use sensors-detect.

```
sudo sensors-detect
```

then launch it with:

```
sensors
```

Comment: OMG, it has been detected;

`ibart@quad:~$ sensors
radeon-pci-0100
Adapter: PCI adapter
temp1:        +49.0°C  (crit = +120.0°C, hyst = +90.0°C)` Is it possible to change its speed setting without aticonfig?

Comment: I will but i need to change its speed setting without aticonfig. How? :p

Comment: Please refer to this question for configuring fan speed: http://askubuntu.com/questions/22108/how-to-control-fan-speed - start from step 3.

Comment: Ok. Thanks but `sensors` doesn't get the fan so I don't think I can manage to change the speed at all. I'll give a try reading. Bye!

Comment: You should also check if you can change the fan speed from UEFI/BIOS

Comment: No I cannot change speed from BIOS; anyway, I need to change it dynamically based on my GPU temp so... ;)

Answer (score 2):

I assume you are trying to change the speed of the system fan in response to the GPU temperature. I think the speed of the GPU fan can only be controlled by the GPU driver (if at all).

Install 'lm-sensors' and 'fancontrol'. There is an excellent set of instructions for doing so [here](https://askubuntu.com/questions/22108/how-to-control-fan-speed)

From the fragment of the output from `sensors` you have posted it seems you have installed but not configured `lm-sensors`. You do so by finding or writing a configuration file for your motherboard and placing it in /etc/sensors.d

As `sensors` is apparently reporting the GPU temperature correctly you don’t need to bother to do this if you don’t mind spurious readings from non-existent sensors and spurious warnings.

Then configure 'fancontrol' to have the fan speed controlled by the GPU temperature.

Comment: Yes, the speed is controlled by the GPU drivers but the fan is noisy. When the python script was working, it was perfect.

I cannot use fanspeed because `/usr/sbin/pwmconfig: There are no pwm-capable sensor modules installed`.

Comment: Please run sudo sensors-detect accepting all the defaults and paste the entire dialog in your question. We will then  try and get it to  detect the fans. You can use paste.ubuntu.com