# How to know if fan control is possible? (old laptop)

Tags: 15.10, fan, fancontrol

I'm running Ubuntu MATE 15.10.

I tried [this answer](https://askubuntu.com/questions/22108/how-to-control-fan-speed) but got:

```
error: /usr/sbin/pwmconfig: There are no pwm-capable sensor modules installed
```

So is there a way of knowing if I can control the fans on my laptop (maybe it's just a matter of installing proper drivers or something like that)?

The processor is Intel(R) Pentium(R) Dual  CPU  T2330  @ 1.60GHz.

EDIT:

Laptop is an old MSI megabook vr201x

@SteveRoome https://paste.ubuntu.com/16129282/

Comment: Please edit your question to include your laptops make and model. Also run sudo sensors-detect again and paste the output in paste.ubuntu.com and insert a link to it.

Comment: @SteveRoome I did as you asked.

Comment: I meant all of it not just the last few lines

Comment: @SteveRoome Sorry. Anyway, you answered bellow.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The MSI Megabook vr201x BIOS does not offer fan control. The vr201x uses the Intel HM76 express chipset. The Intel datasheet for this chipset states that the mobile version of this chipset does not support PWM fan control. I am afraid you don’t have the necessary hardware.

Comment: This is the information I needed. Thanks a lot!