# Controlling fan on Acer Aspire 5315 Using Ubuntu 16.04

Tags: 16.04, acer, overheating, fan

I'm running Ubuntu 16.04 Xenial and need to control my fan speed for my *32-bit* Acer Aspire 5315 with 1 GB RAM. There are old directions for 64-bit [here](http://www.mail-archive.com/acpi-bugzilla@lists.sourceforge.net/msg14582.html), and some for 32-bit [here](http://ubuntuforums.org/showthread.php?t=604158&page=10&p=4651436#post4651436), but these all assume old paradigms (`/proc/acpi/thermalzone` instead of the newer `/sys/class/thermal`—simply replacing the paths doesn't work). The fan never turns on so the system overheats. Acer had a Windows utility that controlled it but this doesn't work on Linux for obvious reasons. The solution appears to be to download a BIOS update issued by Acer, but they've only released a Windows executable and I have Linux on this. I'm trying to find a workaround.

I've installed `lm-sensors` and `fancontrol`, but `pwmconfig` doesn't see any sensors no matter what I try ([I've already tried this](https://askubuntu.com/a/46135/48659)).

Answer (score 0):

I had an Aspire 5720Z, and suffered the exact same issue.

I was actually dual-booting with Vista at the time, so applying the BIOS update was not an issue for me.

For you though, you should try running the update EXE inside of [Windows PE](https://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dn613860.aspx). Might not get you anywhere, but it's worth a shot.

## Disclaimer: It is possible *(not likely)* that doing this ^^^ could brick the motherboard. Of course, any flashing of the BIOS, regardless of the method, carries this risk.

Of course, your other option is dual-booting with Windows...