# Boot problem ubuntu + fan max power

Tags: boot, fan, nomodeset

I have installed the last version of ubuntu using an usb drive (rufus).

My device is an Asus Rog g501 laptop with a Nvidia Gtx 960M if it can helps.
I got some trouble to install it, I finally succeed it by setting the bios as 'nomodeset'.

Now I try to load 'Ubuntu' from my grub but it freezes. I succeed one time to boot by setting it again in 'nomodeset' but it doesn't work at all anymore.

How can I boot on it ?

Are there some options I have to set ?

And the only time I was on Ubuntu, fans were working at their maximum power, it does it only on Ubuntu (no problem on Windows10).

Comment: A quick question, what's your CPU? Is it an Intel Skylake CPU? Thanks

Comment: Yes it is, i7-6700HQ (:

Answer (score 0):

Try choosing the advance options in Grub, and choose recovery options next. It will take you a screen with various options. I can usually just choose continue booting from that screen, and get into my system. It's not a fix, but a workaround, hopefully someone can give you a better answer.

For your second problem, I've notice Ubuntu always run fans at full speed as well. I fixed that by going into my BIOS and setting the fan speed from there. You can also install lmsenors and fancontrol to do it from within Ubuntu, but I think it's best to leave it to the motherboard BIOS if you have that option. Here's some instruction on fancontrol installation and use. [How to control fan speed?](https://askubuntu.com/questions/22108/how-to-control-fan-speed)

Answer (score 0):

To your first question (it's better to separate them actually :-) )

I think you need the proprietary video driver from nVidia, first try to boot to desktop with the nomodeset parameter (to be precise, it's not setting your BIOS to nomodeset, it's adding this to your boot parameter), and open the "Additional Driver" utility from your dash, you should be able to see the nvidia driver there. Install it and reboot, then you should be free from using the nomodeset parameter.

Or, visit nVidia to download the latest driver: http://www.geforce.com/drivers

To your fan problem, I've seen people reporting this issue against Skylake CPU on launchpad.net, the fan keeps running in full speed even the system is cool, it looks like it can be solved (at least on a Lenovo X1) by upgrading the Intel Management Engine Interface (IMEI) firmware. Please follow the links below for discussions.

Reference:

- https://answers.launchpad.net/ubuntu-certification/+question/293087
- https://answers.launchpad.net/ubuntu-certification/+question/293705
- https://bugs.launchpad.net/ubuntu/+source/linux/+bug/1579917

Comment: Thanks for the clues, my Nvidia drivers are already updated, I will keep you up.