# How to disable temperature sensors on Macbook Pro?

Tags: cpu, macbook, temperature

I'm using Ubuntu 16.04 on my MB Pro 2013. Lately, my CPU is throttling to a very low frequency and the fan is running at max whenever I turn on the laptop. It drops down sometime but after a few minutes start throttling again.

[sensors and cpufreq logs](https://gist.github.com/afm-sayem/1d5b23e8e481722f9d169a63dfee3c93)

After running lm-sensors it looks like some of the sensors are reporting -128C as temperature which makes the governor kick in and start throttling the CPU.

Is there any way I can disable these faulty sensors or write a fake valid value to them so that the system thinks everything's alright? I don't care about potential system damage since this laptop is already unusable in this state.

Comment: Have you checked out the guide here? http://askubuntu.com/questions/22108/how-to-control-fan-speed
I don't think it will help you with the cpu speed issue but It may help with the fan speeds.

Comment: The problem is the CPU is dog slow. I don't particularly care about the fan speed tbh. There's an app called macfanctld that can be used to control the fan speed. But at 800Mhz, you can't do much.

Comment: Lol that's like a low end Pentium3 from 2000