# CPU fan problems on Asus - VivoBook X540SA after suspend [Linux Mate]

Tags: suspend, power-management, overheating, fan

The fan control works fine when I boot up my laptop, stating that the fan is running at `3400rpm` when I run `sensors` as well as physically blowing air out of the fan opening.

However, when I suspend my laptop, the fan turns off, and when I un-suspend it, the fan is still in the off state.

I've tried changing the fanspeed by using instructions from the top reply here: [How to control fan speed?](https://askubuntu.com/questions/22108/how-to-control-fan-speed)

But when I get to `sudo pwmconfig` and press enter, it says `There are no usable PWM outputs.`

sudo pwmconfig output - http://pastebin.com/k6NCAmeF

sensors output - http://pastebin.com/UjM0YeKq

Is there a way of fixing this without running a script every time or using a 3rd party program?

I've just installed Linux recently, so I am a complete novice at the OS, so please, if possible, make instructions as simple/clear as possible

Comment: Are you on Linux Mint, or Ubuntu Mate?

Comment: MATE Desktop Environment 1.12.1

Comment: You didn't answer my question. An Ubuntu flavor or Mint?

Comment: @AndroidDev Ubuntu MATE