# Just installed ubuntu and fan won't stop working!

Tags: fan, noise

I installed ubuntu and when I tried to open it everything worked fine, after a few seconds the fan started to run at the max speed without stoping. Right now it still run and I don't seem to find a solution. Any tips woud be highly apreciated, I'm using asus rog gl552vw, thank you!

Comment: hello check this out [power-managment](http://askubuntu.com/questions/22108/how-to-control-fan-speed)

Comment: And check for documentation on thermald - its a new system recently integrated into ubuntu and manages fan speeds. Check for any log entries coming from thermald.

Answer (score 4):

Some motherboards don't have proper linux fan support, so it could simply be a driver issue.

Check to see that your fans are detected. Install lm-sensors:

```
sudo apt-get install lm-sensors
```

And run it from terminal with the command "sensors".
Your fan(s) should be listed as fan1, fan2, etc. If not, then the drivers aren't properly detected.

If they are properly detected, follow the instructions here: [How to control fan speed?](https://askubuntu.com/questions/22108/how-to-control-fan-speed)

Unfortunately, if your fan's aren't detected, you can't directly control their speed.

It could be that your cpu governor is clocking your CPU higher than needed, resulting in higher waste heat that your fans need to dissipate.
Fan control based on temperature is generally managed by the BIOS.

Install the package cpufrequtils:

```
sudo apt-get install cpufrequtils
```

Check your cpu driver with the command:

```
cpufreq-info
```

If it is acpi-cpufreq, do the following:

Change your governor to ondemand with the command

```
sudo cpufreq-set -g ondemand
```

If your cpu driver is intel-pstate, change the governor to powersave and see what happens. If the fan-speed reduces under powersave, you should disable intel-pstate and use acpi-cpufreq, as acpi-cpufreq has far more options when it comes to clocks.

To disable it:

```
sudo nano (or gedit) /etc/default/grub
```

Edit the line GRUB_CMDLINE_LINUX_DEFAULT="~"
and add "intel_pstate=disable".

Then run the command:

```
sudo update-grub
```

And reboot and edit the acpi governor settings as described above.

NOTE: There are generally 4 main CPU governors under acpi-cpufreq: Performance, Powersave, Ondemand, and Conservative. Performance clocks your CPU at its highest clock. Ondemand clocks your CPU higher or lower depending on load. Powersave keeps your CPU at as low a frequency as possible, and Conservative governor prefers the lowest clock, but will jump depending on the load.

Under intel_pstate, there are 2 governors: Performance and powersave. Intel_pstate behaves somewhat differently than acpi-cpufreq and also scales slightly faster, at the expense of customization.

Edit, thermald might also be reporting high thermals, like FrankFoo said. Check the thermald logs.

Comment: I typed sudo cpufreq-set -g ondemand after I detected the driver and disabled it and nothing changes, should I reboot again?

Comment: Try setting it to powersave. Also, install lm-sensors and make sure your fan is detected by Ubuntu.

Answer (score 0):

I found this [article](https://wiki.ubuntu.com/Kernel/PowerManagement/ThermalIssues) in the ubuntu wiki explains how thermald works and how to configure it - had to use it myself :)

Start with troubleshooting it:

- Is it installed? `dpkg -l | grep thermald`
- Is it running? `ps aux | grep thermald`
- Does it have problems? From the article:
  `sudo service thermald stop
  sudo thermald --no-daemon --loglevel=debug`

As thermald should be responsible for the fan control on all systems, we must first know if it reports problems.

Mine is working fine, but the fan does something completely different :)) But that is a different story I guess ...

Answer (score 0):

I had this problem on an Asus laptop.  Changing the kernel solved it.   When using Ubuntu 14.04 then kernel 4.1 was ok but not later versions.   On upgrading to Ubuntu 16.04 the problem came back, but was solved by changing the kernel from 4.4 to 4.15.  I did not try any of the other versions between 4.4 and 4.15