# HP probook 455 g6 fan issue

Tags: 18.04, power-management, fancontrol

My CPU fan is running constantly even doing nothing on my hp probook 455 g6.

Spec :

```
Processor  : AMD Ryzen R7 2700U
GPU        : Radeon vega mobile gfx
Motherboard: HP 85D9

OpenGLrender : Unknown

Kernel : 5.3.0-40 generic
```

I have used `tlp`, but it doesnt reduce fan speed or

`sudo sensors`

Output :

```
amdgpu-pci-0500
Adapter: PCI adapter
vddgfx:           N/A  
vddnb:            N/A  
edge:         +44.0°C  (crit = +80.0°C, hyst =  +0.0°C)

k10temp-pci-00c3
Adapter: PCI adapter
Tdie:         +44.5°C  (high = +70.0°C)
Tctl:         +44.5°C
```

`sudo pwmconfig`

> /usr/sbin/pwmconfig: There are no pwm-capable sensor modules installed

Followed threds without any luck :

[very-high-fan-speed-on-ubuntu-18-04](https://askubuntu.com/questions/1032109/very-high-fan-speed-on-ubuntu-18-04)

[ubuntu-18-04-high-cpu-fan-crazy](https://askubuntu.com/questions/1034052/ubuntu-18-04-high-cpu-fan-crazy-basic-usage)

[just-installed-ubuntu-and-fan-wont-stop](https://askubuntu.com/questions/827626/just-installed-ubuntu-and-fan-wont-stop-working)

My laptop have a serious power consumption issue, It runs approximately around 4-4.5 hours with normal loads.

really frustrated now with this issue.

Comment: Hi. Seven months later, did you fixed?

Comment: @MiguelGilMartínez No, its not fixed.