# There are no usable PWM outputs

Tags: fan

I just installed ubuntu and I'm trying to fix the fan issue because it's alwaysi working , even when I open the laptop, I'm using an asus rog. I was trying to follow this tutorial [How to control fan speed?](https://askubuntu.com/questions/22108/how-to-control-fan-speed)  but got stucked to the part when I type `sudo pwmconig` , there it asks me

```
Are you sure that
you want to setup this output for manual control? (n)
```

and after I press n, it says `There are no usable PWM outputs.`
Any tips for solving would be highly appreciated, really looking to fix this major issue. BTW, I installed lm-sensor and this is what I got till the end

```
acpitz-virtual-0
Adapter: Virtual device
temp1:        +29.0°C  (crit = +103.0°C)

nouveau-pci-0100
Adapter: PCI adapter
temp1:            N/A  (high = +95.0°C, hyst =  +3.0°C)
                       (crit = +105.0°C, hyst =  +5.0°C)
                       (emerg = +135.0°C, hyst =  +5.0°C)

coretemp-isa-0000
Adapter: ISA adapter
Physical id 0:  +30.0°C  (high = +100.0°C, crit = +100.0°C)
Core 0:         +26.0°C  (high = +100.0°C, crit = +100.0°C)
Core 1:         +28.0°C  (high = +100.0°C, crit = +100.0°C)
Core 2:         +26.0°C  (high = +100.0°C, crit = +100.0°C)
Core 3:         +26.0°C  (high = +100.0°C, crit = +100.0°C)

asus-isa-0000
Adapter: ISA adapter
cpu_fan:     25500 RPM
temp1:        +29.0°C
```

SOLVED: [This post](https://jeremymdyson.wordpress.com/2016/04/27/ubuntugnome-16-04-on-asus-rog-gl552v/) helped me fix all the issues ;)

Comment: You should not insert *n*. That means you do **not** want to setup manual control. Insert *y* instead.

Answer (score 5):

I've faced the same problem on a similar Asus laptop and ended up writing my own fancontrol config, since I was unable to get `pwmconfig` working.

Here's what I ended up using.

`/etc/fancontrol`

```
INTERVAL=2
DEVPATH=hwmon3/pwm1=
DEVNAME=hwmon3/pwm1=
FCTEMPS=hwmon3/pwm1=hwmon3/temp1_input
FCFANS=hwmon3/pwm1=hwmon3/fan1_input
MINTEMP=hwmon3/pwm1=50
MAXTEMP=hwmon3/pwm1=100
MINSTART=hwmon3/pwm1=60
MINSTOP=hwmon3/pwm1=30
MINPWM=hwmon3/pwm1=30
MAXPWM=hwmon3/pwm1=255
```

With this config I could start fancontrol by running `sudo fancontrol` and as a deamon with `sudo service fancontrol start`

I found it useful to run `watch sensors` and [`stress --cpu 4`](https://linux.die.net/man/1/stress) when tweaking the config to confirm that fancontrol keeps the temperature at a ok level, even when all cpu cores were running at 100%.