# ubuntu 16.04 pwmconfig 'no working fan sensors'

Tags: amd-processor, fancontrol

I'm trying to control my ubuntu server's fan speed. It has an Asrock 970 extreme4 with an AMD 8350.

I installed fancontrol etc however when I run pwmconfig it outputs:

```
Found the following devices:
   hwmon0 is nct6776
   hwmon1 is fam15h_power
   hwmon2 is k10temp

Found the following PWM controls:
   hwmon0/pwm1           current value: 255
   hwmon0/pwm2           current value: 255
   hwmon0/pwm3           current value: 255

Giving the fans some time to reach full speed...
Found the following fan sensors:
   hwmon0/fan1_input     current speed: 0 ... skipping!
   hwmon0/fan2_input     current speed: 0 ... skipping!
   hwmon0/fan3_input     current speed: 0 ... skipping!
   hwmon0/fan4_input     current speed: 0 ... skipping!
   hwmon0/fan5_input     current speed: 0 ... skipping!

There are no working fan sensors, all readings are 0.
Make sure you have a 3-wire fan connected.
You may also need to increase the fan divisors.
See doc/fan-divisors for more information.
```

Meaning I get no fancontrol config file so I'm not exactly sure what is going on.

Comment: I had a similar problem with pwmconfig, but I managed to figure out how to write a fancontrol config file manually. http://askubuntu.com/a/868442/190584

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Not really the best fix ever but I just turned the fan down manually so my server is not loud as all hell.

```
echo 170 > /sys/class/hwmon/hwmon0/pwm2
```

Comment: Just to comment on this, slowing your fans like this might not be a good solution. The FX 8350 runs extremely hot. You should make sure the temperatures are safe when running `stress -c 8` with `lm-sensors`.

Comment: @A.J. Ruckman It's a self contained watercooler so it runs pretty cool anyway. The highest I've ever had the thing get is 30*c and it's on all the time.