# Laptop with AMD A8 CPU overheats, fan not at highest speed, Ubuntu 14.04

Tags: overheating, fan

I have 'PackardBell EasyNoteTV' laptop which overheats (over 95 degrees)  when watching youtube video. I know about 'indicator-cpufreq' but it seems like the CPU fan doesn't run at it's highest possible speed. I don't know the exact speed it runs at, but when I go to BIOS setup it turns louder. I've tried to monitor the exact fan's speed with 'sensors' and 'pwmconfig', but it says: 'There are no pwm-capable sensor modules installed'.

How to force the fan to run at it's highest possible speed or how to monitor it's actual speed?

Answer (score 0):

Have you tried the fancontrol package?

```
sudo apt-get install fancontrol
```

If you have multiple fans, you might need to figure this out using

```
sudo pwmconfig
```

Visit [How to control fan speed?](https://askubuntu.com/questions/22108/how-to-control-fan-speed) for more details.

Comment: From man page:  
"For  easy  configuration,  there's  a  script named pwmconfig(8) which lets you interactively write your configuration file for fancontrol."  
pwmconfig was mentioned above.