# AMD rx480 fan manual speed control not working

Tags: amd-graphics, fan

Newcomer in the Ubuntu community, running dual OS 16.04LTS and Windows 10.
I recently installed AMD drivers for my Rx480 card and was now trying to control the fans behavior manually.

Having an issue to do so depsite following this thread strictly [How to control fan speed?](https://askubuntu.com/questions/22108/how-to-control-fan-speed)

running `pwmconfig` show me following

```
Testing pwm control hwmon1/pwm1 ...
  hwmon1/fan1_input ... speed was 4011 now 3738
    no correlation
  hwmon3/fan1_input ... speed was 1804 now 1819
    no correlation
  hwmon3/fan2_input ... speed was 808 now 815
    no correlation
```

I then run correlation and define Min-Max and threshold temps for the sensor dedicated to my GPU but when trying to save the config and reboot to make it active,I am getting below error message and my GPU fans spins full throttle.

```
Settings of hwmon1/pwm1:
  Depends on hwmon1/temp1_input
  Controls 
  MINTEMP=20
  MAXTEMP=60
  MINSTART=150
  MINSTOP=100
  MINPWM=0
      MAXPWM=255

Select fan output to configure, or other action:
1) hwmon3/pwm5         4) hwmon3/pwm1         7) Just quit
2) hwmon3/pwm3         5) hwmon1/pwm1         8) Save and quit
3) hwmon3/pwm2         6) Change INTERVAL     9) Show configuration
select (1-n): 8

Saving configuration to y...
mv: cannot create regular file 'y': Permission denied
chmod: cannot access 'y': No such file or directory
Configuration saved
```

I am using `xsesnors` to monitor temps and they seem correct for my CPU (although fan speed seems too high so I will need to manage that later) but is close to 60degC idling for the GPU due to fan running only at 450rpm or so.

Appreciate any guidance on what I am doing wrong here.

Thanks in advance.

Comment: i am not sure if this is against the forum rules but can I bump because I am still stuck with this issue where the conf file can not be created so my GPU temp still too high for my taste at idle

Comment: reinstalled sensors and fancontrol programs then cleaned up the settings through pwmconfig more carefully and I am all good now, CPU, case and GPU now controlled as I wish. please close thread.