# Fix Acer CPU fan speed

Tags: power-management, acer, fancontrol, aspire

a couple of months ago, I had to switch to a new notebook and picked the *Acer Aspire A515-51G*. According to reviews, the device would be a neat bundle of silence, battery life and reasonable power. Especially the silence is what I'm aiming for and unfortunately Acer did a terrible job, from my point of view, when designing the cooling solution.

### Problem

Instead of deciding for a low fan speed, which leads to low noise, the fan idles (great) and gradually increases its speed depending on the CPU load.
However, while working on my notebook (e.g. browsing, text editing, programming) my can keeps wavering and switches to different speeds every 2 seconds or so.
My brain is incapable of blending these reoccurring noises out which is stressing me.

I know that there are threads on how to control the fan speed [similarly to SpeedFan on Windows](https://askubuntu.com/questions/22108/how-to-control-fan-speed). Though it'd be great, `fancontrol` doesn't seem to support my device or built-in notebook fans (controlled by the motherboard) in general.

Hopefully, I'm not the only one here struggling with such problems and someone came up with a solution to this.

### Potential Solutions

At the moment, I can see some potential solutions:

1. specialized software to control Notebook fans via the EC, such as [Notebook Fan Control](https://github.com/hirschmann/nbfc)
2. make `fancontrol` detect/support the built-in fan
3. keep a moderate load on the CPU to keep the fan from wavering which, of course, would waste energy and money

Is there someone with experience in this matter, especially concerning the Acer Aspire 5 series? What can I do to keep the fan from wavering?