# Motherboard fan throbbing after suspend

Tags: suspend, 17.10, power-management, fan

I have recently started manually suspending<sup>1</sup> my computer<sup>2</sup> (Dell Precision T5500 - yes, it's a bit old...), and I have started noticing something strange when it wakes up again.

The motherboard fan starts "doing its own thing".  Only the motherboard fan - all the others are normal.

Before suspending it's all nice and calm, and the fans react nicely to the cooling requirements.  However after resume the motherboard fan starts running with a sinewave pattern, at about 0.25Hz.  Audibly it's an "ooooEEEEooooEEEEoooo" sound.

Graphing that fan using `lm-sensors` and `gnuplot` shows the almost perfect sinewave form of the speed changes:

[image]

I've seen plenty of posts that talk about fans being full on after resume, but never anything with this bizarre kind of pattern.  It's like the hysteresis of the fan control goes completely out of whack and it's reacting almost immediately to the smallest of changes, and effectively oscillating.

So, has anyone ever heard of anything like this before? Is there some way I can set the fan control hysteresis to prevent this kind of oscillation?

Ideally I'd like to be able to run a simple command that undoes whatever has been done by suspending - be that setting something in /sys or whatever.

By the way, `fancontrol` doesn't work well on my system - it can't get the fan speeds, even though the fan speeds are obviously changing when it tries them out, so it defaults to 100% speed on all fans, which makes it sound like a wind tunner.

17.10 lacks the pwmX_enable entries in /sys to be able to set the fan mode. Whether that's a change in Linux, or just something that's particular to the `dell_smm` hwmon I don't know. (Flicking through the source to [dell-smm-hwmon.c](https://elixir.free-electrons.com/linux/v4.13/source/drivers/hwmon/dell-smm-hwmon.c) it looks like it doesn't implement that interface).

---

1. `systemctl suspend`
2. Linux dell 4.13.0-32-generic #35-Ubuntu SMP Thu Jan 25 09:13:46 UTC 2018 x86_64 x86_64 x86_64 GNU/Linux -- DISTRIB_DESCRIPTION="Ubuntu 17.10"

Comment: Are there any options in the BIOS to control this fan ? You say "motherboard fan" - so its directly on the mainboard (southbridge?) ? Do you see any strange temperatures with lm-sensors ? You can try to control it [from ubuntu](https://askubuntu.com/a/46135/783023) as well as the BIOS.

Comment: I shall do another graph in a moment of the mobo temperature to compare.

Comment: Actually, I don't have access to that temperature information, only the fan speed.  Note that the motherboard fan is distinct from the chipset fan in this system. I have processor, motherboard, and chipset fans. I guess I need to open her up and make sure of which fan is which.

Comment: `fancontrol` doesn't like my system much. It complains it can't get the PWM values for the fans, and ends up ramping the fans all to 100% before exiting.

Comment: By the way, when working properly the fan runs at a constant 1145RPM ±1RPM. There's nothing in the BIOS that I can find for configuring fans.

Comment: Do you have a picture of your fan setup ? If it is not a chipset fan, a CPU fan or a case fan - what is it ?

Answer (score 0):

Same problem with a T5500 BIOS A02, ubuntu 16.04.
On wake up, the motherboard fan pulses and wins 500 rpm compared to normal state.
[image]

On normal use:
[image]