# Ubuntu 18.04 on a Lenovo T560 - fan spins like crazy after wake-up from sleep mode

Tags: 18.04, lenovo, fan, fancontrol

If we use the machine with shutdown + cold start: no issues.

But, if we use the sleep function (closing the lid, sleep) and opening the lid later, it will (but randomly, ex.: 2 days later or in just a few hours, etc.) produce very high fan speeds.

Ubuntu 18.04.1 LTS, installed a few months ago, all packages up-to-date.

Intel(R) Core(TM) i5-6300U CPU @ 2.40GHz

Lenovo T560, bought a few months ago.

cpufreq-info says governor is on 1.62-1.8 GHz, all cpus are in powersave mode.

top says there is NOTHING that needs high cpu, only ~5-10% max.

max temperature is: acpitz-virtual-0 temp1 is 48C according to "sensors".

**The big question**: how can I debug or solve this issue? Looks like there is a bug with Ubuntu 18.04 + Lenovo T560?

Is there a software, which defines, at which temperature the fan should start? Normally, when we cold boot the machine, the fan doesn't even turns on.

Or should I open a bugreport?

Sometimes we can fix the high fan running with a lid close/open, but usually only a poweroff/cold start fixes it.

Comment: What does psensor show? Same problem with ubuntu 16.04 on a desktop dell precision T5500 - https://askubuntu.com/questions/1006141/motherboard-fan-throbbing-after-suspend/1120656#1120656. It seems to be an old bug: found this issue with ubuntu 12 or 13.