# /usr/sbin/pwmconfig: There are no pwm-capable sensor modules installed with a SuperMicro mainboard

Tags: server, hardware, fan, fancontrol

Trying to follow these instructions:
[How to control fan speed?](https://askubuntu.com/questions/22108/how-to-control-fan-speed?utm_medium=organic&utm_source=google_rich_qa&utm_campaign=google_rich_qa)

sensors-detect added this module: coretemp

I get this error when runnting pwmconfig:
/usr/sbin/pwmconfig: There are no pwm-capable sensor modules installed

I am using this mainboard, having connected two PWM fans to it:
https://www.supermicro.com/products/motherboard/atom/A2SDi-4C-HLN4F.cfm

Update: I contacted supermicro and they said that there was no official support for this on Linux, but IPMI is supported. With that being said, if someone were to discover a hack or similar to do it, please answer here.

Comment: Do you have fan control enabled in your BIOS settings? Are you sure the fans have speed control? What does `sudo sensors-detect` give you?

Answer (score 0):

The issue is that your board has IPMI management which has different tooling. You can control anything you like... as long as you do it over a network.

So connect up the IPMI network port (I'd just loop it into one of your extra ports as a server), and then install IPMIView to connect. (I haven't done this on mine yet).

Perhaps you can't change much in there, and need to use the `ipmitool` command line directly. That works without connecting the LAN port... but I can't be bothered learning it at this stage.

*In summary, not much of an answer, but has keywords that should help somebody else find their way and elaborate on this*